# How do I install a module globally using npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

I recently installed Node.js and npm module on OSX and have a problem with the settings I think:

```
npm install [MODULE] is not installing the node.js module to the default path 
which is /usr/local/lib/node_modules.
```

Answer (score 389, accepted):

If you want to install a npm module globally, make sure to use the new `-g` flag, for example:

`npm install forever -g`

The general recommendations concerning npm module installation since 1.0rc (taken from [blog.nodejs.org](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/)):

> - If you’re installing something that you want to use in your program, using
>     require('whatever'), then **install it
>     locally**, at the root of your
>     project.
> - If you’re installing something that you want to use in your shell, on the
>     command line or something, **install
>     it globally**, so that its binaries
>     end up in your PATH environment
>     variable.

I just recently used this recommendations and it went down pretty smoothly. I installed forever globally (since it is a command line tool) and all my application modules locally.

However, if you want to use some modules globally (i.e. express or mongodb), take this advice (also taken from [blog.nodejs.org](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/)):

> Of course, there are some cases where
>   you want to do both. Coffee-script and
>   Express both are good examples of apps
>   that have a command line interface, as
>   well as a library. In those cases, you
>   can do one of the following:
>
> - **Install it in both places**. Seriously, are you that short on disk
>     space? It’s fine, really. They’re tiny
>     JavaScript programs.
> - **Install it globally, and then npm link coffee-script or npm link express**
>     (if you’re on a platform that supports
>     symbolic links.) Then you only need to
>     update the global copy to update all
>     the symlinks as well.
>
> The first option is the best in my
>   opinion. Simple, clear, explicit. The
>   second is really handy if you are
>   going to re-use the same library in a
>   bunch of different projects. (More on
>   npm link in a future installment.)

I did not test one of those variations, but they seem to be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Isaacs should replace the entire npm manfile and git wiki with the above text. Could clear up the mass confusion.

Comment: shweeet. This came in handy, I got caught by this change. At some point npm install gave command line access then it vanished and I wasn't following the project closely enough to catch the transition.

Comment: This explains why I had a node module end up in my Apache config directory . . .

Comment: From [blog.node.js.org](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/) :  Usually global binaries are installed in {prefix}/bin and global modules are installed in {prefix}/node_modules and local modules are in ./node_modules, executables go in ./node_modules/.bin/ . You can run `npm prefix` to get the local prefix, and `node prefix -g` to see the global prefix :)

Comment: "If you’re installing something that you want to use in your program, using require('whatever'), then **install it locally**, at the root of your project." - I think, it's not a good idea if the module contains compiled binary: it have to be re-compiled on linux and windows properly. I think such kind of modules have to be set using NODE_PATH environment vriable (http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders)

Comment: Just want to add that the -g flag can be put at any position as argument after npm install. Example: "npm install -g forever", works too

Answer (score 8):

On a Mac, I found the output contained the information I was looking for:

```
$> npm install -g karma
...
...
> ws@0.4.25 install /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
...
$> ls /usr/local/share/npm/bin
karma nf
```

After adding `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` to the `export PATH` line in my `.bash_profile`, saving it, and `source`ing it, I was able to run

```
$> karma --help
```

normally.

Answer (score 5):

I like using a package.json file in the root of your app folder.

Here is one I use

```
nvm use v0.6.4
npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

I had issues installing Express on Ubuntu:

If for some reason NPM command is missing, test npm command with `npm help`. If not there, follow these steps - http://arnolog.net/post/8424207595/installing-node-js-npm-express-mongoose-on-ubuntu

If just the Express command is not working, try:

```
sudo npm install -g express
```

This made everything work as I'm used to with Windows7 and OSX.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You need to have superuser privileges,

```
 sudo npm install -g <package name>
```

Comment: is there no concept of "globally" being "global" to your account but shared amongst all your projects?

Answer (score 0):

### Recommended steps as per official doc worked for me on my Macbook.

#### Summary steps:

1. Instance nvm using following command:

   curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash

You can check the latest version on this page:
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

2. create .zshrc at home directory if file is already not present.

   touch .zshrc
3. put following content in .zshrc file

> export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && .
> "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

4. Install nvm using command

> nvm install --lts

4. restart terminal - you are ready to install global package using npm now.

Answer (score 0):

Since npm version 8 `-g` or `--global` flag is deprecated as per warning I'm getting in the console (official docs yet to be updated):

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
```

So new command to install modules globally is

```
npm install forever --location=global
```

Where `forever` is the name of the package you want to install.

Comment: This seems to have been a bug on Windows, [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401421/message-npm-warn-config-global-global-local-are-deprecated-use-loc)

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu, set path of node_modules in ***.bashrc*** file

> export PATH="/home/username/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"

Answer (score -5):

You might not have write permissions to install a node module in the global location such as `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, in which case run npm install -g package as root.