# When should I use npm with "-g" flag and why?

Tags: npm

I've started using npm for JavaScript package management recently. Although I do have a fair understanding of package management in different environments (let’s say using *apt*, *rvm/gem*, and *pythonbrew/virtualenv/pip*), I don't quite understand how npm fully fits in.

I would like to know more on how the "-g" flag works and why should I use it.

As in most blogs and wiki, they refer to using "-g" when installing without explaining why, and I understand that these packages are installed globally.

- But why should I always install these packages globally?
- What does it mean to install these packages without the "-g" flag?
- What do I do to installed packages locally, let’s say sandboxed for different projects?
- How can I then, make a list of npm packages used in a project and bundle it in the project if I needed it to check it in with version control (if possible at all)?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

`-g` is the **global install flag**, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817874/node-js-npm-is-not-installing-module-in-the-default-path). It's covered in detail in [this node blog post](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/).

The rules of thumb:

- Install globally if the package provides command-line tools
- Install locally if you're using the package as part of your application
- Install globally *and* locally if both use-cases apply

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does "install globally and locally" mean I run the command `npm install -g http-server` and then run `npm install http-server` in my app directory?

Comment: You can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606341/what-does-npm-install-g-do, I hope am not late.

Answer (score 5):

While [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909986/when-should-i-use-npm-with-g-flag-and-why/8951576#8951576) is correct, be aware that there is also `npx` which allows to conveniently run local tools.

For more information, see *[Introducing npx: an npm package runner](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/162869356040/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner)*