# What is the --save option for npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm

I saw some tutorial where the command was:

```
npm install --save
```

What does the `--save` option mean?

Comment: You can use shortcut -S and -D there -S is --save and -D is '--save-dev.          --save (or simple -S): Package will appear in your dependencies.
 --save-dev (or simple -D): Package will appear in your devDependencies.

Comment: @WiredPrairie thanks I was trying `npm install (--help | -h | -help ..)` and nothing.

Comment: thx @Dmitri, I had the same issue. come on NPM add that to your MAN page for your tool

Comment: I don't understand the rationale behind the decision of removing even just a mention of this option from the docs and help page *without* also deprecating it, at the very least, with a warning in the tool itself. Meanwhile newbies are exposed to it via zillions of tutorials. Then they try to find out what it does and have to waste 20 minutes perusing the docs, to eventually end up reading npm history on stackoverflow. Oddly enough preventing this sort of massive waste of time (if the popularity of the question is any indication) is one of the purposes of documentation.

Comment: As of 2020 it does not exist as parameter anymore. See full answer in this thread for further info instead of the comments to the question.

Comment: @MichaelEkoka I am using React-Native for the first time and it is the finickiest piece of development software I have ever had. So far I've spent well over 20 hours debugging dependencies and zero time coding. It's great. There is no long term shared views between the modules. It's chaotic as hell and this is just another example it it.

Comment: As of now installed modules are added as a dependency by default, so the --save option is no longer needed. Thus, it's optional at the time of posting this comment. Not sure few seconds/minutes/hours afterwards. because they enjoy changing these options every often.

Comment: Since new npm version no longe needs `--save`, but I am curious what did it save without `--save` before npm 5? global?

Comment: @Arst it did install the package to `node_modules/`, but not add it to the `package.json`. This meant you quickly forgot what packages your app was dependent on. Beautiful times.

Comment: @MichaelEkoka if they remove the option then all the newbies following old tutorials on the internet will struggle to follow along the tutorial due to an "unknown option error", best to keep it there and npm will just ignore it.

Answer (score 3543, accepted):

**Update npm 5:**

As of [npm 5.0.0](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500), installed modules are added as a dependency by default, so the `--save` option is no longer needed. The other save options still exist and are listed in the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) for `npm install`.

*Original answer:*

Before version 5, NPM simply installed a package under `node_modules` by default. When you were trying to install dependencies for your app/module, you would need to first install them, and then add them (along with the appropriate version number) to the `dependencies` section of your `package.json`.

The `--save` option instructed NPM to include the package inside of the `dependencies` section of your `package.json` automatically, thus saving you an additional step.

In addition, there are the complementary options `--save-dev` and `--save-optional` which save the package under `devDependencies` and `optionalDependencies`, respectively. This is useful when installing development-only packages, like `grunt` or your testing library.

Comment: Seriously, is this documented anywhere? I couldn't find it on Google or in the `npm` help.

Comment: It would be nice if documentation for this showed up when `npm install --help` was used.

Comment: @MarkStosberg: It is listed under `npm help install`, which brings up the man page for `npm-install` on my machine.

Comment: I wanted to update all of my not-versioned (version = *) dependencies and set them to a fixed version. `npm install --save` does not update these in the package.json if I'm correct. If someone else wants to do what I did as well, see the next hideous command you can run:

    cat package.json | sed -E 's/"([a-z -_.]*)":[ ]*"\*",?/\1/g' | sed -E 's/[ ]*["|{|}].*//g' | tr '' ' ' | xargs npm install --save

-frbl

Comment: Use `--save --save-exact` or `--save-dev --save-exact` to pin the semver range to a particular version, rather than using a caret.  Also worth noting is that if you do e.g. `npm install sails@balderdashy/sails#master --save --save-exact`, you'll pin the dependency of the most recent commit on the master branch of the specified GitHub repo.

Comment: -S, --save: Package will appear in your dependencies.

Comment: surprised this isn't the default, like composer

Comment: @jimsmith: As of npm 5.0, it is the default.

Comment: Does "npm update" on NPM 5 modifies package.json by default?

Comment: @IgorOkorokov: By default, I don't think so. `npm update` will comply with whatever version spec you already have in your package.json (so, it may perform an update, but only to a version that matches the specified pattern). If you want to save the updated version to your package.json, you can [pass `--save`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update#recording-updates-with---save).

Comment: @voithos For me NPM 5 updates package versions in package.json. To avoid it i need to run 'npm update --no-save'

Comment: I know I shouldn't downvote an answer because I think that NPM has made a dumb decision. But, it's so compelling. :)

Comment: It appears that the obsolete save option has been removed from the official documentation of npm install.

Comment: Just ran `npm install -g --save @google-cloud/vision`, it saved into `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`, but it's not added into **package.json** at all. Any thought?

Comment: so all these people adding --save to their npm commands these days are doing it out of habit.

Comment: Now that --save is the default you can use --no-save to not automatically add the dependency to  your package.json

Comment: @Jeb50 - *remove* `-g`, to add it to your project's package.json.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8951576/199364, https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders

Comment: Amazing that this is not documented anywhere but no matter. I noticed in the last couple of years that npm install and npm install --save did the same thing.

Comment: It still makes a difference. E.g. installing react-router-dom fails without `--save`.

Comment: I have npm version 6. E.g, when I write npm install json-server, I already see it dependencies in package.json. In this case there is no difference between without save and with save.

Answer (score 370):

*Update as of npm 5:*

As of npm 5.0.0 ([released in May 2017](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500.html)), installed
modules are added as a dependency by default, so the `--save` option
is no longer needed.
The other save options still exist and are listed in the documentation
for `npm install`.

---

*Original Answer:*

**To add package in dependencies:**

```
npm install my_dep --save
```

or

```
npm install my_dep -S
```

or

```
npm i my_dep -S
```

**To add package in devDependencies**

```
npm install my_test_framework --save-dev
```

or

```
npm install my_test_framework -D
```

or

```
npm i my_test_framework -D
```

package.json
[image]

Comment: be careful using shortcut versions like `-S` `-D` as they must be uppercase. I always make this mistake and npm doesn't complain or add it to package.json

Comment: It doesn't complain because `-s` (lowercase) is for the `--silent` option, and `-d` is for loglevel info which are both valid shortcuts.

Answer (score 180):

*Update as of npm 5:*

As of npm 5.0.0, installed modules are added as a dependency by default, so the --save option is no longer needed. The other save options still exist and are listed in the documentation for npm install.

---

*Original answer:*

It won't do anything if you don't have a `package.json` file.  Start by running `npm init` to create one.  Then calls to `npm install --save` or `npm install --save-dev` or `npm install --save-optional` will update the `package.json` to list your dependencies.

Comment: Just found out that it works retroactively (it seems). You can run your `npm install --save-dev` first, then npm init and your package.json will be populated.

Answer (score 47):

According to [NPM Doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

[image]

So it seems that by running `npm install package_name`, the package dependency should be automatically added to [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/), right?

Comment: I guess --no-save is to use when you want functionality of like npm<5

Comment: I see, `npm config ls -l` shows that by default, save-xxx options are all false, only save is true.

Comment: Looks like npm will not fire any error if you put a none exist option, like --save-xxxxxx. It just ignore it and the default behavior --save-prod will be in affect. Maybe --save comes from some old npm version.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50206643/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use `-S`, `-D` or `-P` which are equivalent of saving the package to an application dependency, a development dependency or production dependency. See more NPM shortcuts below:

```
-v: --version
-h, -?, --help, -H: --usage
-s, --silent: --loglevel silent
-q, --quiet: --loglevel warn
-d: --loglevel info
-dd, --verbose: --loglevel verbose
-ddd: --loglevel silly
-g: --global
-C: --prefix
-l: --long
-m: --message
-p, --porcelain: --parseable
-reg: --registry
-f: --force
-desc: --description
-S: --save
-P: --save-prod
-D: --save-dev
-O: --save-optional
-B: --save-bundle
-E: --save-exact
-y: --yes
-n: --yes false
ll and la commands: ls --long
```

This list of shortcuts can be obtained by running the following command:

```
npm help 7 config
```

Answer (score 20):

#### npm v6.x update

Now you can use one of `npm i` or `npm i -S` or `npm i -P` to install and save a module as a dependency.

`npm i` is the alias of `npm install`

1. `npm i` is equal to `npm install`, meaning the default save module as a dependency;
2. `npm i -S` is equal to `npm install --save` (npm v5-)
3. `npm i -P` is equal to `npm install --save-prod` (npm v5+)

### Check out your npm version

```
npm -v

6.14.4
```

### Get npm cli help information

```
npm -h

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help <term>   search for help on <term>
npm help npm      involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /Users/xgqfrms-mbp/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.14.4 /Users/xgqfrms-mbp/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.0/lib/node_modules/npm
```

#### Get npm install help

`npm help install` alias `npm -h i`

```
npm help install

# OR, alias
npm -h i
```

Output:

```
npm install (with no args, in package dir)
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<tag>
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<version>
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<version range>
npm install <alias>@npm:<name>
npm install <folder>
npm install <tarball file>
npm install <tarball url>
npm install <git:// url>
npm install <github username>/<github project>

aliases: i, isntall, add
common options: [--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional] [--save-exact] [--no-save]
➜  ~
```

### References

*[npm-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)*

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Use:

`npm install package_x --save`

The given package (package_x) will be saved in file *package.json* inside dependencies.

If you add

`npm install <<package_x>> --save-dev`

then it will be saved inside **devDependencies**.

Comment: What does your answer contribute that other answers haven't covered already?

Comment: @Pedro A -- My suspicion is that the guy rewrites what he just read; then has his friends give him up-votes.

Answer (score 12):

As of npm 5, it is more favorable to use `--save-prod` (or `-P`) than `--save` but doing the same thing, as is stated in [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install). So far, `--save` still works if provided.

Comment: This needs to go to the top to save us all an eyesore reading variations, contradictions and thread hijacks. SO needs to encourage succinct answers with valid URLs so we can avoid CRUD and get on with our work. (Quora has a neat  'Is this answer relevant' etc and I had even before that suggested to SO to do this)  \n  Sucks that the official node doc has no mention of older (defunct) options and most node references seem to be pre-5.0, sending our heads for a spin.

Answer (score 10):

As of npm 5, npm  will now save by default.

In case, if you would like npm to work in a similar old fashion (no autosave) to how it was working in previous versions, you can update the *config* option to enable autosave as below.

```
npm config set save false
```

To get the current setting, you can execute the following command:

```
npm config get save
```

Source: *[Here’s what you need to know about npm 5](https://blog.pusher.com/what-you-need-know-npm-5/)*

Answer (score 10):

–npm install --save or -S: When the following command is used with npm install, this will save all your installed core packages into the dependency section in the *package.json* file. Core dependencies are those packages without which your application will not give the desired results.

But as mentioned earlier, it is an unnecessary feature in the npm 5.0.0 version onwards.

```
npm install --save
```

Answer (score 7):

`npm install --save` or `npm install --save-dev` is why we choose one option between these two, while installing the package in our project.

Things are clear from the previous answers that `npm install --save` will add an entry in the `dependency` field in the [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/) file and other one in `dev-dependency`.

So the question arises: Why do we need an entry of our installing module in package.json file, because whenever we check in code in Git or giving our code to someone, we always give it or check it without the *[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)* folder, because it is very large in size and is also available at a common place, so to avoid this, we do that.

So then how another person will get all the modules that is specifically or needed for that project so answers is *from the package.json* file that have the entry of all the required packages for running or developing that project.

So after getting the code *we simply need to run the `npm install`* command. It will read the *package.json* file and install the necessary required packages.

Answer (score 5):

**npm i (Package name) --save**

Simply, using the above command we’ll not need to write the package name in your [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/) file, it’ll auto add its name and dependency with version that you’ll need at time when you go for production or set up another time.

**npm help install**

The above command will help to find out more options and correct def.shown in the picture:

[image]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48182529/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, Will keep it in mind for further posts/answers. Thanks @PeterMortensen

Answer (score 5):

The easier (and more awesome) way to add dependencies to your package.json is to do so from the command line, flagging the npm install command with either --save or --save-dev, depending on how you'd like to use that dependency.

Answer (score 2):

In npm version 4, if you run the command `npm install express` without the `--save` or `--save-dev` flags, npm will still install the `express` package, but it will not add it to the `dependencies` or `devDependencies` section of your `package.json` file.

To explicitly save the dependency in the `package.json` file, you should use the `--save` flag:

```bash
npm install express --save
```

If you don't use the `--save` flag, the package will be installed locally in the `node_modules` directory, but the information about the dependency won't be added to the `package.json` file.

Starting from npm version 5 and later, npm introduced the automatic saving of dependencies without the need for the `--save` flag. If you are using a version of npm that is 5 or later, running `npm install express` will automatically add the dependency to the `dependencies` section of your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using --**save** in the **npm** command to install a package, this means that your project will install those dependencies in the production environment, for example, if you install a library to manage dates.

```
npm install moment --save
npm i moment -S (same result)
```

> (this is for a production environment)

```
npm install moment --save--dev
npm i moment -D (same result)
```

> (this is for a development environment)