# How do I load bootstrap using npm?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I have a npm project that uses jquery.

`var $ = require('jquery');`

I also have an index html file that references bootstrap.

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="my-script.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Now do I need to a separate load for jquery for bootstrap as it depends on it?  I was recently using `jqueryify` instead of `jquery` and I did not need the separate load.

Can anyone recommend a loading pattern for bootstrap with use with require?

Comment: For the people out there looking for the correct answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773767/purpose-of-installing-bootstrap-through-npm/35580597#35580597

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Bootstrap is now a supported node package by the bootstrap guys.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/bootstrap

What this means is you can now require bootstrap in code.  So.

`npm install bootstrap --save`

`npm install jquery --save`

foo.js

```
var $ = require('jquery');
window.$ = $;
require('bootstrap');
```

Comment: What about CSS? Do we have to @import in our SASS files to the node_modules folder? Seems dirty.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo yes you would need to. I disagree that it is dirty.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo I want to expand on my comment. You don't necessarily need to. You just need to make sure that the CSS file is loaded. Could just be a `<link>` tag in your .html file. Or you could use sass/less/postcss to import in the file. I don't use bootstrap but in my postcss file i can call `@import 'normalize.css'` just like I would require modules in javascript. To me, that is clean.

Comment: Note that if you're using the `bootstrap-sass` npm module instead of regular `bootstrap`, the `require('bootstrap')` line would need to be `require('bootstrap-sass')`.

Comment: This was helpful, but I also needed an alias in my Laravel Mix Webpack config file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49576317/470749

Answer (score 15):

If you have some trouble to use `require('jquery')`, there is a more simple way to do it. Just redirect node modules folders (without using any `require()`).

```
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')); // redirect bootstrap JS
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist')); // redirect JS jQuery
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')); // redirect CSS bootstrap
```

And on your views, just use simply :

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you want to install the latest version of [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/), and that you are using `node` 10+ which uses `npm` at least 5.6+ (I used it for `node` v12.14.1 and `npm` 6.13.6, and it works properly):

```
npm install bootstrap
npm install jquery
npm install popper.js
```

Notice that you don't need to pass [`--save`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install/19578808#answer-19578808) since after `npm` 5.0.0 installed modules are added as a dependency by default.

Now, assuming you have a file called `index.html` at the same directory of `node_modules`, you need to add the following to your `head` tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

You also need to add the following before `</body>`:

```
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Notice the comment: *jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS.* This is important since Bootstrap depends upon JQuery and Popper.js.

Answer (score 2):

You can try assigning it to global jquery property.

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//install expose-loader
npm install jquery --save  //Installing jquery and saving to package.Json
npm install bootstrap --save//Installing boostrap and saving to package.Json
npm install expose-loader --save-dev//Installing expose-loader and saving to package.json

// webpack
module: {
rules: [
{
     test: require.resolve('jquery'),
     loader: 'expose-loader?jQuery!expose-loader?$'
}
]}

// javascript file 
var $ = require("expose-loader?$!jquery"); 
require('bootstrap');
require('jquery.easing');
```

Comment: please add a description with your code what it is doing and why should the OP use it, it would prevent your answer being flagged as low quality.

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn add bootstrap-sass
yarn add jquery
```

For style, I use gulp sass which need to include Paths for bootstrap

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

var sass = require('gulp-sass');

pipe(sass({includePaths: ['node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets']}).on('error', sass.logError))
```

For JavaScript, I assign jquery to window.jQuery as bootstrap-sass needed:

```
window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-sass');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Laravel Mix (Webpack), so I had to add this alias to `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    ...
    resolve: {    
        ...
        alias: {        
            "bootstrap": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"),
        }
    },
});
```

My `package.json` has `"bootstrap": "^4.0.0",` within devDependencies.

Then in my javascript file for my view, I use:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
window.$ = $;
require('bootstrap');
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/#npm also helped.

Answer (score -3):

Add this link below into head

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

Add these links at the end body tag

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```