# Purpose of installing Twitter Bootstrap through npm?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, npm, cdn

Question 1:

What exactly is the purpose of installing Twitter Bootstrap through npm? I thought npm was meant for server side modules. Is it faster to serve the bootstrap files yourself than using a CDN?

Question 2:

If I were to npm install Bootstrap, how would I point to the bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css files?

Comment: The main use case I can think of is using [Browserify](http://browserify.org) for your frontend JS development.

Comment: @cvrebert: thanks for providing the tl;dr answer :)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

1. The point of using CDN is that it is *faster*, first of all, because it is a *distributed* network, but secondly, because the static files are being cached by the browsers and chances are high that, for example, the CDN's `jquery` library that your site uses had already been downloaded by the user's browser, and therefore the file had been cached, and therefore no unnecessary download is taking place. That being said, it is still a good idea [to provide a fallback](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx).

   #### Now, the point of bootstrap's npm package

   is that it provides bootstrap's **javascript** file as a **module**. As has been mentioned above, this makes it possible to `require` it using [browserify](http://browserify.org/), which is the most likely use case and, as I understand it, the main reason for bootstrap being published on npm.
2. #### How to use it

   Imagine the following project structure:

   ```
   project
   |-- node_modules
   |-- public
   |   |-- css
   |   |-- img
   |   |-- js
   |   |-- index.html
   |-- package.json
   ```

In your `index.html` you can reference both `css` and `js` files like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Which is the simplest way, and correct for the `.css` files. But it is much better to include the `bootstrap.js` file like this somewhere in your `public/js/*.js` files:

```
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
```

And you include this code only in those `javascript` files where you actually need `bootstrap.js`. [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) takes care of including this file for you.

Now, the drawback is that you now have your front-end files as `node_modules` dependencies, and the `node_modules` folder is usually not checked in with `git`. I think this is the most controversial part, with many [opinions](http://addyosmani.com/blog/checking-in-front-end-dependencies/) and [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19416403/3523645).

---

## UPDATE March 2017

Almost two years have passed since I wrote this answer and an update is in place.

Now the generally accepted way is to use a *bundler* like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) (or another bundler of choice) to bundle all your assets in a build step.

Firstly, it allows you to use commonjs syntax just like browserify, so to include bootstrap js code in your project you do the same:

```js
const bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
```

As for the `css` files, webpack has so called "[loaders](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/)". They allow you write this in your js code:

```js
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

and the css files will be "magically" included in your build.
They will be dynamically added as `<style />` tags when your app runs, but you can configure webpack to export them as a separate `css` file. You can read more about that in webpack's documentation.

In conclusion.

1. You should "bundle" your app code with a bundler
2. You shouldn't commit neither `node_modules` nor the dynamically built files to git. You can add a `build` script to npm which should be used to deploy files on server. Anyway, this can be done in different ways depending on your preferred build process.

Comment: I just did this but keep getting http://localhost:3000/bootstrap 404 (Not Found), any thoughts on this?

Comment: I'd say that "chances are high that, for example, the CDN's jquery library that your site uses had already been downloaded by the user's browser" is an exaggeration

Comment: I have to say that the webpack answer is correct.  But to answer the OP question:  There's no neat way to test if a script/stylesheet loaded.  HTTP/2 may solve these problems with multiplexing.   But for the most part, you can use webpack and the `defer` attribute on your scripts or lazy load files

Answer (score 198):

If you NPM those modules you can serve them using static redirect.

First install the packages:

```
npm install jquery
npm install bootstrap
```

Then on the server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// prepare server
app.use('/api', api); // redirect API calls
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/www')); // redirect root
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')); // redirect bootstrap JS
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist')); // redirect JS jQuery
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')); // redirect CSS bootstrap
```

Then, finally, at the .html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I would not serve pages directly from the folder where your server.js file is (which is usually the same as node_modules) as [proposed by timetowonder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30504532/4838205), that way people can access your server.js file.

Of course you can simply download and copy & paste on your folder, but with NPM you can simply update when needed... easier, I think.

Comment: For those working with a express node project generated by web storm, you need to add the code in your app.js

Comment: I never proposed keeping static front-end files together with server files.

Comment: Do you do those calls to app while loading the js file or inside the ready handler?

Comment: @Pablo, I use it at the very beginning, just like in the code snippet.

Comment: Did you forgot to add fonts for glyphicon?

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves how would i go about doing this with Gulp. How do work in my src directory with bootstrap that is in node_modules then compile to my dist directory when done.

Comment: How can the same `/js` route redirect to two separate directories? How would it handle conflicting files in each?

Answer (score 72):

**Answer 1:**

- Downloading bootstrap through npm (or bower) permits you to gain some latency time. Instead of getting a remote resource, you get a local one, it's quicker, except if you use a cdn (check below answer)
- "npm" was originally to get Node Module, but with the essort of the Javascript language (and the advent of browserify), it has a bit grown up. In fact, you can even download AngularJS on npm, that is not a server side framework. Browserify permits you to use AMD/RequireJS/CommonJS on client side so node modules can be used on client side.

**Answer 2:**

If you npm install bootstrap (if you dont use a particular grunt or gulp file to move to a dist folder), your bootstrap will be located in "./node_modules/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" if I m not wrong.

Comment: you can use a [copy command](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/copyfiles) and call it via a [npm run](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/),  [grunt  task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy), or [gulp task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-copy).   Doing this, I don't need to source control the "node_modules" (just call "npm install" when building/deploying) directory, and I can reference "styles/bootstrap.min.css" instead of "./node_modules/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css".

Comment: If there's a downside to copying the files, it's naturally that you'll have two copies of those dependencies in your repo.  The static redirect method mentioned by @augusto looks more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use npm/bower to install bootstrap if you want to recompile it/change less files/test. With grunt it would be easier to do this, as shown on http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt.
   If you only want to add precompiled libraries feel free to manually include files to project.
2. No, you have to do this by yourself or use separate grunt tool. For example 'grunt-contrib-concat' [How to concatenate and minify multiple CSS and JavaScript files with Grunt.js (0.3.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713273/how-to-concatenate-and-minify-multiple-css-and-javascript-files-with-grunt-js)