# NodeJS dropzone package installation

Tags: node.js, npm, dropzone.js

i want to deploy a dropzone component on a nodes project.

I typed:

```
    npm install dropzone
```

This gives me those files:

```
   node_modules/dropzone/dist/dropzone.js
   node_modules/dropzone/dist/dropzone.css
```

But i do not understand why those files are not automatically copied in public/ folder. I had to copy those files manually to my public/css and public/js folders.
It works fine but i am wondering if my copy is dirty or not. Is there a cleanest way to install dropzone component ?

Comment: Because: [browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Comment: Sorry i don't understand

Comment: I found this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773767/purpose-of-installing-bootstrap-through-npm). Its about Bootstrap but the answers apply to any front-end library installed via `npm`.

Answer (score 0):

because you suppose to include them into your asset Compiling tool, something like laravel mix, laravel elixir, gulp, Webpack or similar.