# Difference between package managers, cdns, and normal includes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, package-managers

I am wondering what's the difference between these 3 ways of including third party code in a project. For example, in bootstrap, I can include the css and javascript with a cdn link, or download the minified versions and include them in the project or install bootstap with a package manager in the directory of my project. I understand that the cdn is not good because maybe there will be a version change and still have the old version's code and it needs internet connection in order to work. But what's the difference between installing bootstrap with a package manager and just download the min versions and include them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Purpose of installing bootstrap through npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773767/purpose-of-installing-bootstrap-through-npm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some quick comparison points:

- If you are not connected to the internet, your NPM package will still work.  Your CDN link will not.
- CDN usually only hosts the most popular stuff.  If you want to use a less popular package, you'll want to use NPM.
- Updating NPM packages is easier, especially since some forms will look for major/minor updates.  You'd have to change your CDN link by hand.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real difference.  What happens with a package manager is that it puts it in a pre-specified directory in your project.  That package may include easy ways of including it easier like bundling, but in the end, a package for something like bootstrap just goes and gets the files and puts them in your project.  No different than you doing it yourself.