# Do npm bootstrap and downloaded locally work the same way?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm

Should install Bootstrap on node via npm or download and link it externally? Do both of these option work the same way? Also, how I can link the CSS file if I will install it through node?

Would really appreciate your comments and perspective.

Thanks,

Comment: possible answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773767/purpose-of-installing-bootstrap-through-npm