# Adding Bootstrap to index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I'm stuck trying to add Bootstrap to my index.js file as per instructions on Bootstrap's site.  Their suggestion errors out when I try it.  I'm pretty sure there's something I'm missing, but I don't know what.

index.js is:

```
const express = require('express');
const hbs = require('hbs');
import 'bootstrap';

const app = express();

hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('App listening at port 3000!')
});
```

Error out is:

```
import 'bootstrap';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

My package.json is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "hbs": "^4.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9"
  },
```

Hmm! When I added the following  to the head of my index.hbs file it seems that bootstrap works for rendering the navbar properly now, but I'd like to achieve the same by using bootstrap installed through node npm.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: What version of node do you use? or What do you use to transpile your code? import is es6 feature so probably your environment doesn't support it

Comment: $ node -v is v8.4.0

Comment: You can't use `import` keyword but you can use `require` check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773767/purpose-of-installing-twitter-bootstrap-through-npm)

Comment: Has any of available answers answered your question? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `imports` in nodejs environment if you don't use babel. You should use `require`.

Also, you are trying to import `bootstrap` in your `server.js` file.

**I believe you want to import `bootstrap` in your `app.js` file. Your entry javascript file.**

In your case I would just use **CDN**:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped. :) I don't how does your stack look like but in general the problem was that you were trying to use frontend library in backend environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `import` keyword, you either have to use babel to transpile the code, OR use the `.mjs` file format. But this is not the main issue in your code.

You are trying to import bootstrap to NodeJs, which doesn't make much sense. NodeJs is server side javascript, bootstrap is for the frontend.

You should be using some kind of view engine in your application for handling frontend components. Checkout `embedded javascript` or `pug` for example.

However, nowadays people tend to use a frontend framework instead. Checkout popular choices like React, Vue, or Angular. React has a tool called `create-react-app` which makes it really easy to get started with.

Lastly, if you can give some insight on what you are trying to do with bootstrap, we may be able to give some more help.

Comment: Yes, I'm using handlebars (hbs) for the view engine. And, I'm just using Bootstrap for adding the navbar, footer and grid components to parts of the page(s).