# Electron: How to import or include CSS installed using npm package manager in our index.html?

Tags: node.js, electron

During development there is `node_modules` folder in the root directory of our Electron project which contains all packages we have installed. So, during development we can write something like this to import our CSS file to our webpage:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
```

How can we include CSS for a project which is intended to be packaged and distributed without `node_modules`?

Edit: After some research I found out that `node_modules` are not meant to be used this way (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773767/purpose-of-installing-twitter-bootstrap-through-npm)). Still, if something changes in future please feel free to add your answer.

Link to the repository I started with: https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some research, and since you are using the original boilerplate, I installed it and did the same as you said. Since your main issue is importing the style sheets in production when packaged, you can use `electron-packager` to build your app which will result in the latter being independent of the node module you installed during development. You can do these steps for testing:

1. `npm i`
2. `npm i bootstrap --save`
3. added `<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">`
    in the head
4. added `<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>` in the body for the sake of testing
5. `npm install electron-packager --save`
6. Add `"build": "electron-packager . --asar"` to your `scripts` in `package.json`
7. `npm run build`

Then you can see that Bootstrap is being used normally.

Comment: I did everything as you wrote but when I start the packaged app the css styles don't seem to be applied to the app. Do you maybe miss something? Some import or require?

Comment: @Emir I updated the answer with the whole procedure