# How should I import Bootstrap 5 if I downloaded it?

Tags: npm, import, bootstrap-5

I have downloaded Bootstrap through Node Package Manager:

```
npm install bootstrap
```

How should I import bootstrap to my index.html to replace all the links?
Or if I download Bootstrap I only download the CSS?

I would like to replace the following links to the downloaded bootstrap local links:

```
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773767/purpose-of-installing-twitter-bootstrap-through-npm/35580597#35580597 This question and the top two answers might help you.