# What does the --save-dev option mean in npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm

I saw this [here](https://github.com/yatskevich/grunt-bower-task)

```
npm install grunt-bower-task --save-dev
```

What does --save-dev do? Is this the same as doing without it?

Answer (score 17):

The --save option will save the package as well as the version to your packages.json file.

The --save-dev option will save the package under devDependencies which is useful when installing only development packages that you may not want to ship in production.

**--Edit**

Just found this.  Possible duplicate: [What is the --save option for npm install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install)

Comment: how do you enable it on both environments? is `--save` already both?

Comment: @ahnbizcad Sort of.  Save will allow you to use the dependency but it will not create a devDependency in the packages.json file.  It assumes you will use it in production as well as development