# npm install vs. edit package.json and npm update

Tags: node.js, npm

Curious what is the difference between the two procedures:

1. `npm install xyz`
2. edit `package.json`, adding required module names like this:

---

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.4.4",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "body-parser": "*",
    "bson": "*"
  },
```

and then `npm update`

Comment: Technically these 2 do the same thing. If you update the `package.json` file manually adding the "xyz" dependency and run `npm update` it will have the same effect as adding the package using `npm install xyz`.

Adding the package using the npm install command is recommended because it updates the `package.json` file for you and eliminates the potential for human error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just do `npm install package`, it doesn't add it to your package.json. Then, if you want to `npm update` or publish your package, it won't have all of the required packages.

You can also do `npm install --save package`, which will install and add to your package.json. ([see the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally#using-package-json-and-the-save-flag))

Answer (score 5):

Basically package.json stores the dependencies of you application. Everything under "dependencies" is updated when you do `npm update` .

`"bson": "*"` means that it will update to latest version of module `bson`.

When you do `npm install xyz` you are basically installing `xyz` without telling package.json. Next time you do `npm update` npm will update everything under `dependencies` but not `xyz`

Here are the commands that will help you :

1. `npm install xyz` This will install `xyz` without telling `package.json`.
2. `npm install --save xyz` This will install `xyz` and also update `package.json`, so that when next time you do `npm update` it will update `xyz` as well.
3. `npm install` This will install everything under `dependencies` in `package.json`.
4. `npm update` This will update everything under `dependencies` in `package.json`.

Answer (score 2):

Some answers here are outdated.

Quote from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19578808/1041641

> As of npm 5.0.0, installed modules are added as a dependency by default, so the --save option is no longer needed.