# Difference between npm install --save and npm install --save-dev

Tags: javascript, npm

Guys I know that using `npm install -g` we can install the node modules/packages globally, but I am not sure about the options `--save` and `--save-dev`

I have Googled it but still not clear about it. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: You might find some information here: [What is the --save option for npm install?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install)

Answer (score 29):

`--save` adds the third-party package to the package's *dependencies*. It will be installed together with the package whenever someone runs `npm install yourPackage`.

`--save-dev` adds the third-party package to the package's *development dependencies*. It won't be installed when someone installs your package. It's typically only installed if someone clones your source repository and runs `npm install` in it.

Dev dependencies, as the same suggests, are those dependencies that are only needed for developing the package. That can include test runners, compilers, packagers, etc.

Both types of dependencies are stored in the package's `package.json` file. `--save` adds to `dependencies`, `--save-dev` adds to `devDependencies`. [From the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#devdependencies):

> **devDependencies**
>
> If someone is planning on downloading and using your module in their program, then they probably don't want or need to download and build the external test or documentation framework that you use.
>
> In this case, it's best to map these additional items in a devDependencies object.
>
> These things will be installed when doing npm link or npm install from the root of a package, and can be managed like any other npm configuration param. See npm-config(7) for more on the topic.
>
> For build steps that are not platform-specific, such as compiling CoffeeScript or other languages to JavaScript, use the prepublish script to do this, and make the required package a devDependency.

Edit: As of [npm 5.0.0](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500) the installed modules are added as a dependency by default, so the --save option is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks 4 your quick reply

Answer (score 7):

- `--save-dev` is used to save the package for development purpose. Example: unit tests, minification.
- `--save` is used to save the package required for the application to run.

Answer (score 0):

1. `--save-dev` will save npm modules in development dependencies in package.json i.e it will save inside devDependencies object.
2. `--save` will save npm modules dependencies in package.json i.e it will save inside dependencies object.