# npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@*

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am new to React and, starting with building an app, I came up with a problem while installing dependencies. I wanted to include packages like `material-ui/core`, `material-ui/icons`, `react-reveal`, `react-scroll` and `react-slick`.

While installing with this command:

```
npm install @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons react-reveal react-scroll react-slick
```

It showed that they've been installed, and when I started coding it didn't compile it.

That's when I came up with this error:

> npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN tsutils@3.14.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you actually using TypeScript in your project?

Comment: I am not using it, do I need to install it maybe?

Comment: Did you bootstrap your React project with something particular? What are your current dependencies listed in `package.json`?

Comment: i didn use bootstrap. These are currently in package:

"@material-ui/core": "^4.1.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.12",
    "react-slick": "^0.24.0"

Comment: TypeScript was problem after all, thanks

Comment: do not install typescript if you don't need it!

Answer (score 31):

try this:

1. Delete 'package-lock.json' file
2. In the Terminal go to the folder with your project and type 'npm install --save typescript'
3. Then type 'npm install'

It helped me.

Answer (score 27):

You can also resolve this issue by just installing typescript (it's clearly written in the debug output)

```
$ npm install typescript
```

You may also use other package-managers in favor of npm like pnpm or yarn.

Update:
You can also use an npm package that does this for you. Helpful when there are many peer dependencies.

The package is [npm-install-peers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-peers). If you want slightly more control over these, you may want to check out [install-peerdeps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-peerdeps/v/1.10.0?activeTab=readme)

Also, please do a further read on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39079214/9274057).

Answer (score 1):

I will list every little bit of gory detail, just in case for some people it is helpful:

1. Remove package-lock.json (rm package-lock.json) if necessary
2. yarn add @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons react-reveal react-scroll react-slick
3. Read messages to make sure the dependencies were added. If you see any, then yarn add them as well.
4. Change into your node_modules directory (cd node_modules) then list to make sure all your packages and dependencies were installed (ls)
5. Check your App.js to make sure your import has the correct path (whether you really should have a ../ or not)
6. Go to the browser tab that is running localhost:3000
7. Refresh the page (For Chrome, it's the upper left clockwise arrow to the left of where you enter the URL)

Answer (score 0):

While trying to reproduce the same error, on a Windows 10 machine with Node and npm installed, created an app with

```
npx create-react-app APP_NAME
```

If I run

```
npm start
```

the application will run just fine if I go to http://localhost:3000/

[image: React App]

---

In order to fix the problem you're getting, I'd just install Typescript

```
npm install typescript
```

and that should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

add this  in package.json:

```
"peerDependenciesMeta": {
"typescript": {
  "optional": true
}
```

}