# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular2

Tags: angular

Am using angular2 with angular-cli. I need to work with popups so
am trying to install "ng2-opd-popup" module , i got those errors :

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.4.9
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.4.9
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@2.4.9
-- ng2-opd-popup@1.1.21
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.3.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.2.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.3.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@2.3.0
-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 
(node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):  npm WARN notsup SKIPPING 
OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted 
{"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/animations@4.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.2.2 
but none was installed.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.26 requires a peer of 
@angular/core@^4.0.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.26 requires a peer of 
@angular/common@^4.0.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.26 requires a peer of 
@angular/forms@^4.0.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@2.3.0 requires a peer of 
@angular/compiler@2.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.3.0 requires a peer of 
@angular/compiler@2.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.2.4 but 
none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.2.4 but 
none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/platform-
browser@2.2.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.2.4 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but 
none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler@2.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.2.4 but 
none was installed.
```

Does anyone know what could be the cause ??
The package.json file looks like this :

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/common": "^2.4.10",
"@angular/compiler": "2.4.9",
"@angular/core": "2.4.9",
"@angular/forms": "2.4.9",
"@angular/http": "2.4.9",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.9",
"@angular/router": "3.4.9",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.4.9",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.26",
"angular2-modal": "^2.0.3",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.5",
"bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
"chart.js": "2.5.0",
"core-js": "2.4.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"googleapis": "^18.0.0",
"moment": "2.17.1",
"ng2-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
"ng2-charts": "1.5.0",
"ng2-data-table": "^1.0.0",
"ng2-pagination": "^2.0.1",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^1.6.6",
"rxjs": "5.2.0",
"ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
"zone.js": "0.7.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.9",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
"@types/node": "7.0.8",
"codelyzer": "2.0.1",
"jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
"karma": "1.5.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.3.0",
"protractor": "5.1.1",
"ts-node": "2.1.0",
"tslint": "4.5.1",
"typescript": "2.2.1"
}
```

Comment: Unmet peer dependency means you're missing a npm-package that the package you are installing depends on. You'll have to install those other packages that "ng2-opd-popup" wants to work with. This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207380/how-to-install-npm-peer-dependencies-automatically

Comment: Well, i tried npm clean cache then npm install but still having the same issue

Comment: Add your package.json info. The error are pretty clear...

Comment: @Jota.Toledo i did

Comment: You are using mixed dependency versions between 2 and 4. You should choose either 2 or 4.

Comment: Which dependendencies are of version 4 ?