# React-bootstrap not installing

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-bootstrap

I'm having issue installing react and react-bootstrap. I used them in the past and everything was working fine. But now, I seem to have an issue installing or updating them.

After the code line: `npm install --save react-bootstrap` in my terminal, I get these errors:

> npm WARN react-bootstrap@0.32.1 requires a peer of react@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN react-bootstrap@0.32.1 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN react-prop-types@0.4.0 requires a peer of react@>=0.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN react-transition-group@2.2.1 requires a peer of react@>=15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN react-transition-group@2.2.1 requires a peer of react-dom@>=15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN react-overlays@0.8.3 requires a peer of react@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN react-overlays@0.8.3 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN prop-types-extra@1.0.1 requires a peer of react@>=0.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN uncontrollable@4.1.0 requires a peer of react@>=0.11.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Even my past react projects aren't working anymore and I can't find in the docs anything about these errors.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: First try to install react then, react-dom then react-bootstrap.

Comment: That's the thing. When I run 'npm install --save react' , it gives me the same errors..

Comment: I think you have version issue. check react, react-prop-types and all other dependency versions match with the react-bootstrap version. 

use this command: 
'npm ls --depth=0'

This will show report of the installed npm modules.

Comment: Just ran the line. It probably is a version issue since it's showing me react@15.6.2. How can I fix it? (if it's not be reinstalling it directly)

Comment: First thing, these are just warnings. To resolve them, go to "react-bootstrap" installed folder and run command - "npm install" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207380/how-to-install-npm-peer-dependencies-automatically/35207983

Comment: Thank you guys, I actually went in my 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming' and deleted everything that was in my '\npm' folder. Then I went back and fresh installed everything I needed.

Comment: There is probably a better way, but that worked for me and didn't cause any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's an typo in your command line 
    npm install --save react-booTstrap

Comment: Haha I would've felt dumb there. It was actually a typo in my question. I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

add --force after pasting the command in your terminal. The error is a version issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).