# Angular 6 - Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

After updating to Angular 6.0.1, I get the following error on `ng serve`:

```
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/home/Projects/myProjectName".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/home/Projects/myProjectName".
    at Object.resolve (/home/Projects/myProjectName/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node/resolve.js:141:11)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (/home/Projects/myProjectName/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architect.js:132:40)
```

`ng update` says everything is in order. Deleting the *[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)* folder and a fresh `npm install` install did not help either.

My project is based on [ng2-admin](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin) (Angular 4 version). Here are my *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)* dependencies:

```javascript
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.26",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "amcharts3": "github:amcharts/amcharts3",
    "ammap3": "github:amcharts/ammap3",
    "angular-table": "^1.0.4",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.5",
    "angular2-datatable": "0.6.0",
    "animate.css": "3.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "bower": "^1.8.4",
    "chart.js": "1.1.1",
    "chartist": "0.10.1",
    "chroma-js": "1.3.3",
    "ckeditor": "4.6.2",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "easy-pie-chart": "2.1.7",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "3.3.1",
    "google-maps": "3.2.1",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
    "leaflet": "0.7.7",
    "leaflet-map": "0.2.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "1.1.6",
    "ng2-completer": "^1.6.3",
    "ng2-handsontable": "^2.1.0-rc.3",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.0.3",
    "ng2-tree": "2.0.0-alpha.5",
    "ngx-uploader": "4.2.4",
    "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.1",
    "@types/fullcalendar": "2.7.40",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.41",
    "@types/jquery.slimscroll": "1.3.30",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.61",
    "@types/node": "6.0.69",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
    "gh-pages": "0.12.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "standard-changelog": "1.0.1",
    "stylelint": "7.10.1",
    "ts-node": "2.1.2",
    "tslint": "5.2.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "4.0.0",
    "tslint-language-service": "0.9.6",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "typogr": "0.6.6",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "wintersmith": "2.2.5",
    "wintersmith-sassy": "1.1.0"
  }
```

And my *[angular.json](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config)* file:

```javascript
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ng2-admin": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/sass/roboto-fontface.scss",
              "node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "node_modules/ionicons/scss/ionicons.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
              "node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css",
              "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css",
              "node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css",
              "node_modules/ng2-slim-loading-bar/style.css",
              "src/app/theme/theme.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/easy-pie-chart/dist/jquery.easypiechart.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js",
              "node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
              "node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js",
              "node_modules/chroma-js/chroma.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ng2-admin:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ng2-admin:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ng2-admin:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/easy-pie-chart/dist/jquery.easypiechart.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js",
              "node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
              "node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js",
              "node_modules/chroma-js/chroma.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/sass/roboto-fontface.scss",
              "node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "node_modules/ionicons/scss/ionicons.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
              "node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css",
              "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css",
              "node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css",
              "node_modules/ng2-slim-loading-bar/style.css",
              "src/app/theme/theme.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ng2-admin-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ng2-admin:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ng2-admin",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I deleted the node_modules and package-lock.json folders and then typed npm i on the command line. After that, everything was fine.

Comment: sometimes, you might not have node_modules folder at all, maybe fresh clone. run npm install first.

Comment: Do you have folder node_modules ? For me the same error happened, when I cloned my Angular project through GitHub on different laptop. I didn't push folder node_modules to save space. Because I was on cell phone tethering, I decided do not reinstall all packages, but copy node_modules folder from different project on the same laptop. And it worked!

Comment: So many identical answers to this question.

Comment: @SteveSmith I've already flagged a few, but if you notice such answers in the future, you can custom flag them and leave a link to the original answer to get them cleaned up.

Comment: Hey everyone, if the below answers didn't work even after deleting npm_modules and reinstalling, try deleting package-lock.json and try npm install again. I ran into similar issue once and deleting package-lock.json and doing npm install worked for me back then. Hope this helps.

Comment: This one worked for me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62228823/1461862

Answer (score 1346, accepted):

Install `@angular-devkit/build-angular` as dev dependency. This package is newly introduced in Angular 6.0

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

or,

```
yarn add @angular-devkit/build-angular --dev
```

Comment: Exact same error? And the configuration file? are they same as this question?

Comment: Yes. Well, I did some more exploring on this issue. Turns out that it works fine on my Mac Mini, so it will probably has something to do with my Node setup on Windows.

Comment: Then try to delete node_module folder & clean cache & install again

Comment: Try to delete node_module & npm cache... @AmritaSrivastava

Comment: hugo der hungrige [here](https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/49831485/angular+6+and+karma+39can+not+load+quotangulardevkitbuildangularquot+it+is+not+registered39) said:
1. Update all dependencies and make sure the app itself works as intented
2. Replace every occurrence of @angular/cli with @angular-devkit/build-angular in the karma.conf.js
3. Removing the files and the preprocessor configs from the karma.conf.js completely. This is all defined in the angular.json and should be handled automatically by the @angular-devkit karma plugin.

**Doing #3 worked for me**

Comment: Upgrade to angular 7 - the accepted answer fixed the error (have upvoted), but didn't solve the upgrade problem overall. This did https://stackoverflow.com/a/51592138/852806

Comment: Thanks for this. I just hit this problem while attempting to follow the Angular tutorial: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart - seems like someone forgot to update the documentation?

Comment: I don't know why its called devkit if we still need it on prod?

Comment: This command is only making the situation bad by removing the angular devkit

Comment: I had to run in adicional the following command: "npm audit fix --force"

Comment: Seems wonky that I have to execute this command every time I clear out node_modules/.

Comment: just try `yarn` or `npm install`

Comment: This solution not work for me. if any other solution please update

Comment: Question though: if my `package.json` mentioned it needs this package as a dev dependency, why wouldn't NPM fetch it for me, transitively? Seems like a bad UX to me.

Comment: This issue might occur some times due to restricted environment also. check with IT team for angular repo setup internal. Most of the banking services companies will not accept public artifactories.

Comment: Same error. Bad answer.

Comment: I ran with this command: npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular --force

Answer (score 284):

```
npm update
```

It worked like a charm.

Comment: I moved to a new machine halfway through the angular-tour-of-heroes tutorial and pulled the half baked work from source control. This fixed it.

Comment: Nothing "half baked" about not checking in the `node modules` folder. This simply rebuilds your node modules based on your package.json. This is perfectly normal thing to do when you check out a new solution.

Comment: There might be additional packages that are outdated. Run `ng update --all` to try to update all at the same time.

Comment: after i cloned my project in another machine i was having this issue, and this solution worked perfectly, thanks

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 138):

For Angular 6 and above, the working solution for me was:

`npm install`

`ng update`

And finally

`npm update`

Comment: When I do the ng update I got several messages about several specific updates needed.

      Name                               Version                  Command to update
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @angular/core                      4.4.7 -> 8.2.4           ng update @angular/core
      @ngrx/store                          2.2.3 -> 8.3.0           ng update @ngrx/store
      rxjs                                        5.5.12 -> 6.5.3         ng update rxjs

Comment: npm i only without ng update and npm upsdate worked for me (Angular 12).  Anyway thank you so much!

Comment: noo doesnt work

Answer (score 36):

We need to explicitly get devDependencies.

```
npm i --only=dev
```

Comment: This worked for me, same answer in: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10661#issuecomment-392149827

Answer (score 24):

Please follow these five steps. It's definitely worked (my personal experience)

Step 1: `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`

Step 2: `npm cache clean --force`

Step 3: `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Step 4: `npm i`

Step 5: `ng build`

After that, `ng serve`.

Comment: open in browser type cmd:  ng servre --o

Answer (score 22):

If the following command does not work,

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

then move to the project folder and run this command:

```
npm install --save @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Comment: npm install --save @angular-devkit/build-angular
worked for me but only problem was I was trying to run this command from a command prompt which was not run as an administrator, and I entered to execute this command it was not showing any error nothing only cursor was on wait state then I simply run a cmd with admin in it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

I fixed mine by:

1. Delete node_modules folder.
2. run `npm install`

Answer (score 15):

All of the previous answers are correct, but they did not work for me. The only way I was able to make this work was by the following steps/commands:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli@6.0.8
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm install node-sass -g
ng new MY_PROJECT_NAME
cp -r from_my_old_project to_new_MY_PROJECT_NAME
```

Comment: If you are trying to build a library, use `ng new MY_PROJECT_NAME --create-application=false` for the second-to-last command. I had this error on trying to build a library. The `--create-application=false` flag avoids pulling in unnecessary dependencies. (https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#getting-started)

Comment: worked for me after clearing the npm cache and installing again

Answer (score 11):

**For Angular 8**

Install **npm-check-updates** package

Run:

```
$ npm i npm-check-updates
$ ncu -u
$ npm install
```

This package will update all packages and resolve this issue

Notice: After update If you face this issue:

> ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0
>   but 3.6.3 was found instead.

then run:

```
$ npm install typescript@3.5.3
```

**Source [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-update-local-angular-cli-version/)**

Comment: 'ncu' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 9):

`npm install`

Just type `npm install` and run. Then the project will run without errors.

Or you can use `npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular`.

Answer (score 9):

Try this one.

```
npm install

npm update
```

If it shows something like this,

> Run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Do that!

Comment: And when you do that, NPM says 'I sure hope you know what you are doing.'. That gave me the freaks.

Comment: upvoted since it helped - although only partially. After doing this I still had some missing peer dependencies which I install following this idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51063840/2995907

Comment: Are you quoting something? If so, what is the source?

Answer (score 8):

The following worked for me. Nothing else did, unfortunately.

```
npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular
ng update --all --allow-dirty --force
```

Comment: I had a message saying --allow-dirty not installed. But updated my stuff.

Comment: Why does it work? An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57834657/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 7):

The following commands works:

```
npm install
ng update
```

You may see the message "We analyzed your package.json and everything seems to be in order. Good work!"

```
npm update
```

Then try a development build:

```
ng build
```

I got the error with TypeScript and downgraded to:

```
npm install typescript@">=3.1.1 <3.2

ng build --prod
```

All success with a production build.

Below is the working combination:

```
ng --version

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.11.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.11.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.11.0
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.11.0
@angular-devkit/core              7.1.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.0
@angular/cli                      7.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                  7.1.0
@schematics/angular               7.1.0
@schematics/update                0.11.0
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.23.1
```

Answer (score 6):

A working solution for me:

1. Delete the [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder.
2. Run `npm install`

Answer (score 5):

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest
```

solved it for me.

Answer (score 5):

First delete `node_modules` folder

then **Restart system**

Run    `npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular`

and

Run    `npm install`

Answer (score 4):

When we run commands like `ng serve`, it uses the local version of @angular/cli. So first install the latest version of @angular/cli locally (without the `-g` flag). Then update the cli using the `ng update @angular/cli` command. I thing this should fix the issue.

*[Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/)* may help you if you are updating your Angular project.

Answer (score 4):

This error generally occurred when the Angular project was not configured completely.

This will work

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

npm install
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Resolve this  Error: An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser###

Just execute the following command and error was solved

- `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`
- `npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular`
- `npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular`
  ###if this error could not resolve by above command so you update node version###
- npm update npm -g

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
npm i --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

This code installs `@angular-devkit/build-angular` as a development dependency.

It was 100% *tested*.

Answer (score 4):

Just update the Angular version and add the below dependency:

`ng update`

`npm update`

`npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular

Answer (score 4):

I had a library which I created in an older version of Angular.

Now that I upgraded to the latest version 11 the build would fail.

Indeed, the builder has changed.

When doing an `ng build` I was something a somewhat similar error message:

```
Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr/package.json'
```

In the `angular.json` file I had to change the builder property:

```json
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
```

with:

```json
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to the folder where you created the angular project and the delete the node_modules folder.
2. Now open the command prompt and enter in the project which you want to run using [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)).
3. Enter the command

`npm i`

```
or
```

`npm install`

4. Now the command prompt will start installing the new *[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)* files in the project.
5. When the *node_modules* gets installed then, run the project using command

   `ng s --o`

If the above method did not work, then there is some mismatch of the version in npm and then try to install the node_modules.

`npm update`

Generally, this method should work if not worked then try to run this command:

`npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular`

Details and alternative solution: *[Could not find module “@angular-devkit/build-angular”](https://learnprogramo.com/could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular-resolved/)*.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with the same problem just a minute ago. My project was generated using the version 1.6.0 of angular-cli.

1. `npm update -g @angular/cli`
2. editing my [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/), changing the line

   ```
   "@angular/cli": "1.6.0",
   ```

   to

   ```
   "@angular/cli": "^1.6.0",
   ```
3. `npm update`

Comment: This has nothing to do with not being able to find a module. this just means the angular cli module will be updated for any version 1.6.x

Answer (score 3):

Try this first

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

If some error come again for missing packages try

```
npm install
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? How does it work? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56057333/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

That's works for me, commit and then:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today, after upgrading Node.js from v9 to v10.
My environment is set by [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) and I had to remove this command from the my DockerFile:

```
npm link @angular/cli
```

It creates a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to the directory where Node.js is installed.
I guess the `angular/cli` module in it do not have the same version as the one in the [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) directory of my project, and this causes the issue.

Answer (score 3):

All these answers basically say the same

```
npm install -D @angular-devkit/build-angular
npm install
```

But this still may fail if you are in a **library** project like `my-lib` which is inside an Angular workspace:

```
workspace
|-- projects
|    |-- my-lib
|        |-- package.json
|
|-- package.json
```

In this case, make sure to run `npm install` not only in the directory `workspace/projects/my-lib`, but also in `workspace` directly.

Answer (score 2):

- Delete the folder *[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)*.
- Clear the cache using `npm cache clean --verify`.
- And then `npm install` again.

It works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem.

Surprisingly, it was just because the `version` specified in `package.json` was not in the expected format.

I switched from version `"version": "0.1"` to `"version": "0.0.1"` and it solved the problem.

Angular *needs* semantic [versioning](https://angular.io/guide/releases) (also read [Semver](https://semver.org/)) with three parts.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem with the newest version of `@angular-devkit/build-angular` (as of writing this, 11.0.5 was only released 17 hours ago).

Our company is using a Nexus Repository Manager as a npm registry (we do not access https://registry.npmjs.org/ directly). The version was so new, that it wasn't included yet in our Nexus yet.

**Invalidating** the **cache** of the **repository** and `npm install` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had been facing the same issue for two days.

```
ng -v :6.0.8
node -v :8.11.2
npm -v :6.1.0
```

Make sure you are in the folder where *angular.json* is installed. Get into that and type `ng serve`. If the issue still arises, then you are having only dependencies installed in folder *[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)*. Type the following, and it will work:

```
npm i --only=dev
```

Comment: I used ng --version inside the project. It showed me the list with error. So, it means the list didnt had this package installed properly. When I went outside of the app and checked ng --version, so global one didnt even listed it. So, I guess my yarn installtion didnt install the dev dependencies properly

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, none of the provided solutions worked perfectly for me, but grepit's answer inspired me to do the following steps.
I uninstalled Node.js via my OS (Windows 10) and installed it again. Then installed Angular CLI. Then created a new project, and copied my old project's source file into this new one and the error's gone.

Here are the instructions:

1. Uninstall Node.js via your OS and install it again
2. `npm install -g @angular/cli`
3. Rename your project to YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.old
4. `ng new YOUR_PROJECT_NAME`
5. Run this [Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) project (`ng serve`) to make sure that you won't get the error.
6. `xcopy YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.old\src\*.* YOUR_PROJECT_NAME\src /s`

This is the Windows version of copy. Change it based on your own OS.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Ionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_(mobile_app_framework)) forum, this worked for me.

```
npm i @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest
```

Comment: this is not an ionic project.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following worked for me:

`npm audit fix --force`

Answer (score 0):

Delete package-lock.json and do npm install again. It should fix the issue.

** This fix is more suitable when you have created Angular 6 app using ng new and after installing other dependencies you find this error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was because of missing dependencies. The dependencies were missing, because I had forgotten to call:

`npm install`

After calling the above command, all required dependencies are loaded in folder *[node_modules folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)*, and that isn't an issue any more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@next
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the previous answers, but none of them worked for me. I had to downgrade the version of Angular-CLI. I run the command `ng --version` and results:

```
@angular-devkit/architect          0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.10.7
@angular-devkit/core               7.0.7 <-- notice this!
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.2.1
@angular/cli                       8.2.1 <-- and this!
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   7.0.7
@schematics/angular                8.2.1
@schematics/update                 0.802.1
ng-packagr                         4.7.1
rxjs                               6.3.3
typescript                         3.1.6
webpack                            4.19.1
```

I open my package.json and search for the line that define the version of CLI:

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.2.0" -- I changed here to ~7.0.7
...}
...
```

I change the version of `@angular/cli` to **~7.0.7**. Then run `npm uninstall @angular/cli` and install again running `npm install -g angular-cli@~7.0.7`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by installing Angular on a 64-bit operating system. I was getting the error because I was initially running it on a 32-bit OS.

Comment: What operating system? Linux? Windows?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the below commands, your application will work as you expected. Run each command as I mention.

1. `npm list -g --depth=0`
2. `npm i npm-check-updates`
3. *npm install*

And finally, run the below command to open your project in the browser:

```
ng serve --open
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have a package.json.  Make sure you have one.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked when I ran the `npm install` command inside the project folder.

Example: I have shoppingmenu app and I ran the `npm install` command inside that folder.

Answer (score 0):

This error mostly arises when you don't have Node.js modules in your Angular application.

Developers mostly share Angular applications without the Node.js [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder, because it is very big in size and sharing of applications or uploading takes so much time.

It can be fixed with single command , `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for my case:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22603

If there is nothing in the folder `node_modules\@angular-devkit` you might have the same issue.

The `devDependencies` are not installed because you have set the Environment variable `NODE_ENV` to `production` try `development` instead.

Restart commandline and run `npm install` and maybe `npm i --only=dev`

Answer (score 0):

After try many ways, it's still not work until i removed my **yarn.lock** file

Answer (score -1):

**npm i** OR **npm install**

then after, re-run the appliaction.

Answer (score -2):

I just did the below, and it worked.

```
npm install --save-dev
```

Comment: unhelpful comment, try answering why it worked, what was failing, etc.

Answer (score -5):

Your `npm` version is old. Try to run the following command:

```
npm i npm@latest -g
```

Comment: old npm or Node versions does not throw this error "Could not find module “@angular-devkit/build-angular”, the aswear is just install the dependency:npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular