# Can not find module “@angular-devkit/build-angular”

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install, package.json, angular6

Using npm, I followed the getting started directions on the Angular CLI quick start page.

[Angular CLI Quickstart](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

Running `ng serve --open` after creating and going into my new project "frontend" gave this error:

```
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\Users\\Brandon\\project-name\\frontend".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\Users\\Brandon\\project-name\\frontend".
 at Object.resolve (C:\Users\Brandon\project-name\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:141:11)
 at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\Brandon\project-name\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:132:40)
```

I have tried suggestions from the other question similar to mine but it did not work. Answer was to run `npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular`.

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular)

I have also deleted modules, cleared cache, then did an install which also did not work.

package.json:

```
{
 "name": "frontend",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
   "start": "ng serve",
   "build": "ng build",
   "test": "ng test",
   "lint": "ng lint",
   "e2e": "ng e2e"
 },
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^6.0.2",
  "@angular/common": "^6.0.2",
  "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.2",
  "@angular/core": "^6.0.2",
  "@angular/forms": "^6.0.2",
  "@angular/http": "^6.0.2",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.2",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.2",
  "@angular/router": "^6.0.2",
  "core-js": "^2.5.4",
  "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
 },
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.2",
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.3",
  "typescript": "~2.7.2",
  "@angular/cli": "^6.0.3",
  "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.2",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
  "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "~1.7.1",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "protractor": "~5.3.0",
  "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
  "tslint": "~5.9.1"
 }
}
```

angular.json:

```
 {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "frontend": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "frontend-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "frontend:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "frontend"
}
```

Comment: Something to go through, and see if anything might help: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10661

Comment: I would remove the lock file(s) and `rm -r node_modules` and reinstall `npm i` before proceeding. I'll watch this question to help more afterwards.

Comment: @Brandon Lumsden did you fixed this?

Answer (score 20):

> Running ng serve --open after creating and going into my new project "frontend" gave this error:

After creating the project, you need to run

```
npm install
```

to install all the dependencies listed in package.json

Answer (score 12):

I looked inside `node_modules` and apparently, only dependencies are installed, not devDependencies. With the new NPM, we need to explicitly get the devDependencies:

```
npm i --only=dev
```

If you wish to install just the devkit:

```
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

*Joint idea with - ken107(github)*

Answer (score 5):

If you are using angular version 8 please run the below command to fix this issue.

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

Comment: When using code in a question, please put all code into code blocks: usually, indent all code lines by 4 spaces, or surround the code block with 3 backticks (`\`\`\``). For inline code on the same line as non-code, surround the code with a single backtick on each side (`\``).

Answer (score 3):

Use

`npm update`

or run

`npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular`

Answer (score 3):

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

> It's Install @angular-devkit/build-angular as dev dependency. This package is newly introduced in Angular 6.0

Comment: You should add what this does and how this is different from what OP did (--save-dev, non-global).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Learner try this yarn add @angular-devkit/build-angular --dev

Comment: @kashif: Dude, I dont know what the heck is yarn. This command doesnt run in cmd

Answer (score 2):

Another issue could be with your dev-dependencies.
Please check if they have been installed properly (check if they are availabe in the node_modules folder)

If not then a quick fix would be:

```
npm i --only=dev
```

Or check how your npm settings are regarding prod:

```
npm config get production
```

In case they are set to true - change them to false:

```
npm config set -g production false
```

and setup a new angular project.

Found that hint here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10661
(ken107 and lichunbin814)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: Type `npm audit fix` in the commandline. Afterwards I was able to use `ng serve --open` again.

Comment: @Learner Just sharing what was working for me in a similar situation. The other answers didn't work for me at that time, so it may be helpful to some people. I am in no way claiming that it always solves the issue with this error message.

Comment: This also worked for me as well. npm audit fix --force as a last resort

Answer (score 1):

I've just encountered this problem and fixed it. I think the root cause of this problem is ng and current version of node.js (10.6.0) and accompanying npm are not in sync. I've installed the LTS version of node.js (8.11.3) and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem just a minute ago. My project was generated using the v 1.6.0 of angular-cli.

npm update -g @angular/cli
editing my package.json changing the line
"@angular/cli": "1.6.0",
to
"@angular/cli": "^1.6.0",
npm update
did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

D:project/contactlist npm install
then
D:project/contactlist ng new client

D:project/contactlist/client ng serve

this worked for me for some reason i had to delete the client folder and start npm install from the contactlist folder. i tried every thing even clearing the cache and finally this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, as it did not installed

> @angular-devkit/build-angular

The answer which has worked for me was this:

> npm i --only=dev

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating from angular 7 to angular 8 then do this

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

for more information read here https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/blob/master/MIGRATION.MD

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command to get it resolved. Whenever you pull a new project, few dependencies wont get added to the working directory. Run the below command to get it resolved

npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the possible commands listed above and none of them worked for me,
Check if **Package.json** contain "@angular-devkit/build-angular" if not just install it using(in my case version 0.803.19 worked)

> npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.19

Or checkout at [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular?activeTab=versions) website repositories for version selection

Answer (score 0):

Try to install angular-devkit for building angular projects

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Answer (score -1):

did all the above didn't work... may be some issue with NPM

```
Yarn
```

was helpful ..

```
Yarn Install
```