# Cannot find module 'webpack' - Angular

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular6

I just migrated my project from angular v5.x to v6.x and now when I try to start it with `ng serve` I'm getting:

```
Cannot find module 'webpack'
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
  at Function.Module....
```

any help ?

I cleared node modules and:

- `npm cache clean --force`
- `npm install`
- `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest`

but that didn't help

Answer (score 134, accepted):

I had the same issue and this worked for me:

1. Delete these files/ folders (from your Angular root folder):

   - `package-lock.json` (**Not** the package.json)
   - `/node_modules` folder
   - `/dist` folder
2. Execute command (regenerate the `package-lock.json` and the `/node_modules`):

   - `$npm install`

Everything should work now, it was the `package-lock.json` that caused npm to download old versions of dependencies.

Answer (score 43):

I fixed this issue with:

```
delete package-lock.json
delete node_modules
delete dist (if exist)

npm cache clean --force

npm install
```

Answer (score 5):

This error mostly occurs because of **old dependencies**, if at all are not upgraded then it can be deleted manually by deleting the `node_modules` Folder and also the `package-lock.json` file

after that you can clean the Cache (if at all necessary) and then

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

Answer (score 5):

While using `npm link webpack` worked locally, on my CI (GitHub actions) I had the same problem, and to resolve it I used:

```
 npm i --save-dev webpack
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm update --force
```

solved my problem

Answer (score -10):

Try to see if this works...

```
npm uninstall --save webpack
npm install --save-dev webpack
```

Comment: Don't ! In latest angular versions the webpack dependency is manager by the CLI and you shouldn't have a webpack entry in your package.json at all.