# Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/removeAndDo' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-devtools

When ever I try to perform `npm install` to build my `react` part in project.
it throws the error below:

```
*module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/removeAndDo'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\CHUBB\Sourcecode_claimyno_svn\denuncia-claimy\src\main\webapp\js\appReact\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\ExtractedModule.js:30:42)*
```

What is the issue with my react part and what could be a possible solution.

Comment: make sure to only have one webpack version installed

Comment: actually i performed another web pack installation earlier from that the problem persist how can i remove another webpack

Comment: I have posted an answer try that

Comment: I fixed this issue with: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53470468/7569936)

Answer (score 2):

You have to cleaned npm cache:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/
$ npm cache clean --force
$ npm i
```

Comment: Did not solve for me, still running in to same error.

Answer (score 2):

try it:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: Instead of saying *try it* please explain why do you think this will solve OP's problem.