# Angular (npm) prepends an underscore to an existing directory in angular-devkit and gives a "no directory" (ENOENT) error

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Compiling my Angular Electron app gives `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/_models/webpack-configs/browser.js'`. The app does compile and run. The problem emerged after running `npm install`.

My `node-modules` has `../angular-cli-files/models/..`, containing `browser.js`. Weirdly, an underscore is prepended, ie `_models`, in the error message. I'm completely at a loss why this happens. I've tried the suggestions in several  SO answers [Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular); [Cannot find module 'webpack' - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096511/cannot-find-module-webpack-angular/51592138#51592138) and others, but no luck. My search didn't find any examples with an underscore being prepended.

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "five-x",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "FiveX Electron App",
  "main": "main.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run postinstall:electron && electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postinstall:web": "node postinstall-web",
    "postinstall:electron": "node postinstall",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "PORT=4201 npm run postinstall:electron && npm-run-all -p ng:serve electron:serve",
    "start:dev": "npm run postinstall:electron && npm-run-all -p ng:serve electron:serve:dev",
    "build": "npm run postinstall:electron && npm run electron:serve-tsc && ng build",
    "build:dev": "npm run build -- -c dev",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- -c production",
    "ng:serve": "ng serve",
    "ng:serve:web": "npm run postinstall:web && ng serve -o",
    "electron:serve-tsc": "tsc -p tsconfig-serve.json",
    "electron:serve": "wait-on http-get://localhost:4201/ && npm run electron:serve-tsc && electron . --serve",
    "electron:serve:dev": "wait-on http-get://localhost:4201/ && npm run electron:serve-tsc && electron . --serve --tools",
    "electron:local": "npm run build:prod && electron .",
    "electron:linux": "npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --linux",
    "electron:windows": "npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --windows",
    "electron:mac": "npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --mac",
    "test": "npm run postinstall:web && ng test --no-watch --no-progress --source-map=false",
    "test:watch": "npm run postinstall:web && ng test --watch --no-progress --source-map=false",
    "e2e": "npm run postinstall:web && ng e2e",
    "lint": "ng lint --format stylish --type-check",
    "check-licenses": "license-checker --onlyAllow='MIT;ISC;BSD-2-Clause;BSD-3-Clause;Apache-2.0;LGPL;WTFPL;CC-BY-4.0;CC-BY-3.0;BSD;Public Domain;CC0-1.0;Unlicense;Zlib' --excludePackages 'five-x@0.0.1;map-stream@0.1.0;png-js@0.1.1;@mapbox/jsonlint-lines-primitives@2.0.2;gl-mat2@1.0.1;gl-mat3@1.0.0;gl-mat4@1.2.0;gl-vec3@1.1.3;weak-map@1.0.5'",
    "check-format": "prettier --check 'src/**/*.{ts,scss,html}'",
    "format": "prettier --write 'src/**/*.{ts,scss,html}'",
    "license-report": "license-report --output=table --fields={name,licenseType,link}",
    "dependency-graph": "ngd -d documentation/dependency-graph",
    "compodoc": "npx compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d documentation/generated",
    "docs": "npm run compodoc && open documentation/generated/index.html"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.19",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.803.19",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.19",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@compodoc/ngd-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "@kiosk/store": "^1.0.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.4.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.9",
    "@types/plotly.js": "^1.44.16",
    "angular-plotly.js": "^1.4.2",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "chartist-plugin-axistitle": "^0.0.4",
    "chartist-plugin-legend": "^0.6.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.0",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "^2.0.28",
    "core-js": "^3.4.1",
    "electron": "^7.1.1",
    "electron-builder": "^21.2.0",
    "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "license-checker": "^25.0.1",
    "license-report": "^3.0.0",
    "ng-mocks": "^8.1.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^5.7.1",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.8.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "nouislider": "^14.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "plotly.js": "^1.51.1",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "python-shell": "^1.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.5.2",
    "tsickle": "^0.37.1",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "3.7.2",
    "wait-on": "^3.3.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.1.7",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "npm-check-updates": "^3.2.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0"
  }
}
```

`angular.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-electron": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/app",
                "src/styles"
              ]
            },
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/favicon.png",
              "src/favicon.icns",
              "src/favicon.256x256.png",
              "src/favicon.512x512.png"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/global.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-electron:build",
            "port": 4201
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-electron:build:dev"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-electron:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-electron:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills-test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/global.scss"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/app",
                "src/styles"
              ]
            },
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/favicon.png",
              "src/favicon.icns",
              "src/favicon.256x256.png",
              "src/favicon.512x512.png"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "angular-electron-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "angular-electron:serve"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "core-domain": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/core-domain",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/core-domain/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/core-domain/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/core-domain/ng-package.json"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/core-domain/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/core-domain/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/core-domain/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/core-domain/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "projects/core-domain/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "angular-electron",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "fx",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "fx"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out, the part `/models/` in  the path `'node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js'` in `postinstall.js` and `postinstall-web.js` somehow changed to `/_models/`. I've no idea how this happened, as I'd never opened those files.

Changing it back solved the problem.