# Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" with ng serve

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Studying Angular, 
Trying to do [those simple steps](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) for generate new projects, but when I am trying to start ng-serve I got those errors:

```
 Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\Users\\lingar\\AngularProjects2\\project1".
    Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\Users\\lingar\\AngularProjects2\\project1".
        at Object.resolve (C:\Users\lingar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:141:11)
        at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\lingar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:132:40)
        at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\lingar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:43:25)
        at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\lingar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:29:22)
        at DoOperator.call (C:\Users\lingar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:29:23)
        at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\lingar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:24:22)
        at C:\Users\lingar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:22:31
        at Object.subscribeToResult (C:\Users\lingar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:7:45)
        at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (C:\Users\lingar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:75:38)
        at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\lingar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:72:14)
```

Have tried a lot of [those solutions](https://www.google.co.il/search?newwindow=1&ei=uE3GW9qwGJD5gQbQ14a4CA&q=cannot%20find%20module%20%27%40angular-devkit%2Fcore%27%20angular%205&oq=angular%20cli%20could%20not%20find%20module%20%40angular-devkit%2Fbuild-angular%20%5CAppData%5CRoaming%5Cnpm%5Cnode_modules%5C%40angular%5Ccli%5Cnode_modules%5Crxjs%5Cinternal%5Coperators%5C&gs_l=psy-ab.1.2.0i71k1l8.0.0.0.427728.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.X-PpxJWxhsA) without success.

Does someone have ideas ?

**Edit: Solved!**

Thanks to  @Seth McClaine answer in the comments I went to [the Technical Specifications of this module @angular-devkit/build-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular),

From there I took the install command and run it on the cmd :

`npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular` ,

and from then it's working well.

BTW - A weird issue that I've before the solution that only in the root user directory it's worked well.

[@angular-devkit/build-angular specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYMIb.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular

Comment: As I said have tried without success @alokstar

Comment: okay, the other thing i can suggest is, if you updated any of your dependency, then try deleting and installing node modules again and then try to run it.

Comment: build-angular is still WIP according to this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular You may want to look at pulling a previous version of @angular/cli

Comment: Thanks @alokstar tried those things...

Comment: Thanks @SethMcClaine I'll consider this in future problems if will arise. Anyway your answer gave me the direction to the solution and it's solved.

Answer (score 3):

> try this.

```
npm i --only=dev
```

> after that npm install and run you project