# Angular8 error when using ng serve: Could not find module “@angular-devkit/build-angular”

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8

None of the answers here on StackOverflow seemed to help me, maybe because they are all referring to an older version of Angular.

I am a complete newbie trying to start the first Angular project. I did the `npm install -g @angular/cli`

`ng new first-ang`
`cd first-ang`
But when I do `ng serve`, it gives me the " Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "D:\Angular\ang".
See "C:\Users\Susanna\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-hjBvo0\angular-errors.log" for further details."

The error log contains this:

```
[error] Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "D:\\Angular\\ang".
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\Susanna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:151:11)
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (C:\Users\Susanna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:31:40)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (C:\Users\Susanna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:134:55)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Here is what the package.json file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "ang",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.4",
    "@types/node": "~12.7.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0",
    "typescript": "~3.6.2"
  }
}
```

I already tried updating npm and doing pretty much everything that has ever been listed on Stackoverlfow, but with no avail. Does anyone know what to do with this latest verison of Angular?

(links to solutions that I've already tried:
[Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular)
[Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" with ng serve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843908/could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular-with-ng-serve)
[ng serve is not working after Angular 8 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56650590/ng-serve-is-not-working-after-angular-8-update)
)

PS: I noticed my package.json file doesn't have the "angular-cli" dependency. Is this a problem?

Comment: Have your tried this? Remove 'package-lock.json' and 'node_modules', then redo 'npm install'.

Comment: i am seeing the cli in the devDependencies "@angular/cli": "~8.3.3".    are you installing angular at work? if so you will have to configure the proxy that's what i had to do when i had this issue

Comment: were there any errors when you initially build the project?

Comment: @shahidfoy I'm installing at home, could you pleqase tell me what you did with the proxy? :) no but there were some warnings (the project stil got installed)

Answer (score 1):

Run `npm install` in the folder that you have packages.json so that all the required packages are restored. (not `npm install -g`)