# Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" after npm install

Tags: angular

After running `npm install` then `npm update` I got this error when using `ng serve`:

```
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\Users\\Matt\\Coding\\chart".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\Users\\Matt\\Coding\\chart".
```

Then checking the angular version, build-angular is there.

```
ng version
```

--

```
Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.11.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular      <error>
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   <error>
@angular-devkit/core               7.1.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics         7.1.0 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular                7.1.0 (cli-only)
@schematics/update                 0.11.0 (cli-only)
ng-packagr                         <error>
rxjs                               6.3.3 (cli-only)
typescript                         3.1.6 (cli-only)
```

Comment: I think that this can solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular

Comment: i tried the suggestions in that question

Comment: Did you try installing the missing dependency ? npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular

Comment: i got the same error and tried `ng update --all`

Answer (score 3):

I have the same error. I fixed with follow commands:

1. install `build-angular` with this command:

   ```
     `npm i --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular`
   ```
2. then install `build-ng-packagr`:

   ```
     `npm i --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr`
   ```
3. finally install `ng-packagr`:

   ```
     `npm i --save-dev ng-packagr`
   ```

> note: the version of installed package will be related with `angular` version.

I hope is useful.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was uninstall my @angular/cli , then removed node_modules directory and package-lock.json file, then reinstall @angular/cli. Example:

```
#npm uninstall  @angular/cli@7.1.3
#rm -rf node_modules
#rm package-lock.json
#npm install  @angular/cli@7.1.3
```

Comment: Would you lilke to improve this answer by adding more explanation and maybe some details on "How?". Think of the beginners who might want to use your advice.

Comment: `package-lock.json` is automatically generated for any operations where npm modifies either the `node_modules` tree, or `package.json`. It describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of intermediate dependency updates. Source: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

Answer (score -1):

Haven't you seen these two lines?

```
@angular-devkit/build-angular      <error>
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   <error>
```

I encountered similar issues today and solved by `npm uninstall  @angular/cli@7.3.8`; just that, nothing more and then I can run `ng build --prod --stats-json` as expected.

---

Before uninstallation, there is the error similar to yours but mine is `@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr`.

```
$ ng build --stats-json
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr" from "/home/hearen/git/repos/ng-hue-lib".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr" from "/home/hearen/git/repos/ng-hue-lib".
    at Object.resolve (/home/hearen/git/repos/ng-hue-lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node/resolve.js:141:11)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (/home/hearen/git/repos/ng-hue-lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architect-legacy.js:153:40)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (/home/hearen/git/repos/ng-hue-lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (/home/hearen/git/repos/ng-hue-lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:30:22)
    at /home/hearen/git/repos/ng-hue-lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:99:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Observable.toPromise (/home/hearen/git/repos/ng-hue-lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:97:16)
    at BuildCommand.initialize (/home/hearen/git/repos/ng-hue-lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:67:96)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:279:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:696:3)

...

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.13.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.13.8
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   <error>
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.13.8
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.13.8
@angular-devkit/core               7.3.8
@angular-devkit/schematics         7.3.8
@angular/cdk                       7.3.7
@angular/cli                       7.3.8
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   7.3.8
@schematics/angular                7.3.8
@schematics/update                 0.13.8
ng-packagr                         5.0.1
rxjs                               6.4.0
typescript                         3.1.6
webpack                            4.29.0
```