# How to fix the angular project generation problem

Tags: angular

I am trying to install a new angular starter project with `ng new project-name` but everytime I am ending up with the below error codes

```
PS H:\Desktop\cool-app> ng serve
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "H:\\Desktop\\cool-app".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "H:\\Desktop\\cool-app".
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\G01205980\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:141:11)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\G01205980\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect-legacy.js:153:40)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\G01205980\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\G01205980\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
    at C:\Users\G01205980\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:99:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Observable.toPromise (C:\Users\G01205980\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:97:16)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (C:\Users\G01205980\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:130:86)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
PS H:\Desktop\cool-app> npm install
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? n
PS H:\Desktop\cool-app> npm install
[       ...........] \ postinstall: sill install executeActions
```

Comment: What is your CLI version, is it outputting another error before that, have you submitted this issue to the github repository of the CLI, do you have any admin permissions going on, what is the command you type ... ? Give some context !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular)

Comment: H:\>node -v
v8.10.0

H:\>npm -v
6.9.0

My problem is quite different, my installation process is getting stuck at thispoint  [       ...........] \ postinstall: sill install executeActions, Its been half an hour and still i am seeing the same message.

Answer (score 2):

looks like node dependencies are not installed

run `npm install` then try again

Comment: This should be suggested in the comments\

Answer (score 1):

Install `@angular-devkit/build-angular` as dev dependency.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

or,

```
yarn add @angular-devkit/build-angular --dev
```

Comment: I did the same but could not see the progress here after
 npm install [ ...........] \ postinstall: sill install executeActions.

Comment: try to clear the cache and try **npm cache clear --force** and the **npm install**

Comment: I tried clearing npm cache but its getting stuck at the same place.

Comment: try to restart the PC :) sometime I face the same issue

Comment: almost i restarted it 2 times hoping it will work this time but no luck.

Comment: Try to reinstall the angular cli .. last hope

Comment: I lost the last hope just now. I think i need to perform Xen meditation for 15 mins and should give it a try again....