# Angular dependencies not found

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am having problems creating angular projects. Until a few moments ago it was working fine, but now when I create a new project( `ng new <project_name>` ) the `node_modules` folder that contains all installed dependencies doesn't appear anymore.

I can't even run( `ng serve` ) the project because of this. It just prints on the screen:

```
Node packages may not be installed. Try installing with 'npm install'.
Error: Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package.
```

I tried all these commands:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev @angular/cli
npm uninstall --save @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install --save @angular/cli
npm install
```

Especially `npm install` that only prints `up to date in 662ms`. Also in other projects that have the folder, when I try to install other dependencies it only shows as in the example:

```
changed 36 packages in 14s
2 packages are looking for funding
```

I search the project and find nothing. I don't know what else to do. If someone can please help me solve this I would really appreciate it.

---

**EDIT** ---------- **SOLUTION**

I finally managed to solve it with the option of an older version of npm, which in my case was `npm install -g npm@7`, and then I was able to use the `npm install` command. The `node_modules` folder with all the dependencies is working fine now. The only thing you have to watch out for later is the dependency conflicts.

Comment: Try deleting `node_modules` folder and then just run `npm install` in the project root (without mentioning any dependency name)

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't work

Comment: @lys_18 Did you run commands in correct directory?

Comment: yes, directly in my project folder

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying it cannot find "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server". so you should install it using the following command. The command will fail if you do not have peerDependencies set to true so I will add the force flag.

```
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular --force
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it didn't work

Comment: Ok refer to the following links, you may find an answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/angular-6-could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56623458/could-not-find-the-implementation-for-builder-angular-devkit-build-angulardev