# File differs from alreay included file name only in casing : update from Angular 7 to 8

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8

I have just update my angular project to angular 8 (using angular cli 8.3.20). When I try to run "ng build" it appears this king of error for multiple files but I am sure that the casing in my project is correct!

I don't know how to figured out this!

Here a screenshot of some of the multiple errors (all of the same kind)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a86CN.png

Comment: please provide your step that you use to from which version which one

Comment: Are you using Windows? we had issues in the past with Windows and Git causing casing issues.

Comment: I am using mac os, for passing from 7 to 8 I have followed the first answer of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56650590/ng-serve-is-not-working-after-angular-8-update

Answer (score -1):

The issue is some of the file names and imports are not using same casing

For example

your file name is like `my-service.ts`

and you imported it like

`import {MyService} from './services/My-service';`

For example your authGuard

[image]

Comment: I am sure that I have no files with this issue so I don't know where the errors come from

Comment: @Dangrad for sure you have, I found one in your screen shot

Comment: @Dangrad glad to hear it's solved, please kindly mark my post as answer, so that if somebody else has same issue then he/she will know this is the solution

Comment: This error appears after renaming a file although you have the correct import, see: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25460#issuecomment-526273944