# Cannot determine versions of "@angular/cli" local installation is broken

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular7, node-modules

So, I've broken my local installation after install moment plugin.
This [Momento plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-moment)

After this installation, when I put command `ng serve` to running project, the return by the console is:

> Cannot determine versions of "@angular/cli". This likely means your
>   local installation is broken. Please reinstall your packages.

I've followed this: [Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular) but nothing.

So, I've tried to reinstall angular, but nothing, I've tried to run npm update but nothing...
I don't know how to fix this, and I need to work.

Also, tried to re-checkout by git, but nothing.

The project was born in Angular 7 with Material.
How can fix this?

Comment: As I understand, the error appeared after moment plugin installation. Did you try uninstall moment, then reinstall `@angular/cli` and then reinstall moment?

Comment: yes i've tried to uninstall and re-install angular/cli but doesn't works..

Comment: Just try to uninstall angular/cli globally and then install it with the version that your project is. Also check in case you installed momento globally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Restore your old package.json / package-lock.json, then delete all your contents of node_modules. After, from your project root run the following to rebuild the contents of node_modules:

`npm install`.

If you don't have a copy of the package files from before the problems started, first, uninstall moment - local and global - to prevent it from installing itself when you run `npm install`.

`npm uninstall moment ngx-moment`

`npm uninstall -g moment ngx-moment`

Then go with the step of deleting all your node_modules contents before running `npm install` in your project root.

Answer (score 5):

Please, check your version of `@angular/cli` (both, local and global) as Angular 8 is released. Also, try to match your version with current [ngx-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-moment)'s `@angular/cli` version (i.e. `"@angular/cli": "~7.0.3"` as of June 2019)