# Unable to run Angular project [Angular 6]

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular) solution. But it is not working for me. I've cloned a project from gitlab and trying to run the same. First see the output of my `ng version` command.
[image]. I want to run an `angular 6` project available on gitlab. You can clone it from [here](https://gitlab.com/SisenseJS/angular6-sample). I extracted the project and tried `npm install`. To which I'm getting the below errors:
[image: <code>npm install</code> screenshot]. However I still tried `ng serve`. 
[image: ng serve screenshot]
I know It will definitely fail now. Please tell me whether something is wrong with the project or I am doing some mistake. Even with `run as admin` cmd prompt i'm getting this:
[image]

Comment: does it also happen if you use Windows Power Shell (run as administrator) instead of normal CMD?

Comment: Remove `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` And try  `npm install --unsafe-perm=true` this command with administration permission.

Comment: Yes @AlessandroSantamaria. I tried running the commands with admin privileges but `ng serve` is still failing. However `npm install` was successful this time.

Comment: Its just a permissions issue. check write permissions of your angular project directory.

Comment: @ShrutikaPatil Maám but rest of my angular projects are working fine.

Comment: It could be a problem with the sass-loader version, I had similar issues before.

Comment: I've had a similar problem once and this solved it for me: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1579#issuecomment-227662011 mainly the `npm rebuild node-sass`.

Comment: @ShrutikaPatil, @Alessandro. I've added screenshot of `ng serve` while using run as admin.

Comment: @Tanzeel I have cloned and tried running project, its working fine at my end. I am also getting the same error. Have you checked the source code?

Comment: Just open types.d.ts file and apply semicolon(;) there or download rxjs again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken the clone and tried running ng serve, I got the same issue. However, I am able to run the project by changing rxjs version. Try using following command :

```
npm install rxjs@6.0.0 --save
```

Reference: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4540

Comment: I changed in the package.json and then run `npm install`

Comment: It worked @Shrutika. thanks. Can you please guide me How and Why.