# Showing "Could not find module @angular-devkit/build-angular" after Installing ChartsModule

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-charts

The project was smooth and running. I install the ChartsModule  from "https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts" and started to show the following message. [image]

what is failed in the project? npm update does not help either.

Comment: what version of angular are you using? and what version of ng2 charts you installed?

Comment: Try removing `node_modules` and running `npm i` again

Comment: @ng-suhas Angular cli 8.0.3,  "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0", I think its the latest version of ng2 charts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular

Comment: Thanks, I have removed and re-installed node modules worked.