# Ionic app: an unhandled exception occurred: Could not find module “@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/utils”

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I created an empty blank ionic app (without capacitor), added the cordova plugin and install the google-plus package.

In the devDependecies section of the packages.json I have:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.1",
"@angular-devkit/core": "^11.0.1",
"@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
"@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
```

I proceeded in building the app by doing:

> ionic cordova build android --prod --release --verbose

But I get the exception:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/utils'
> Require stack:
> C:\dev\myapp\node_modules@ionic\angular-toolkit\builders\utils\index.js
> C:\dev\myapp\node_modules@ionic\angular-toolkit\builders\cordova-build\index.js
> C:\dev\myapp\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
> C:\dev\myapp\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
> C:\dev\myapp\node_modules@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
> C:\dev\myapp\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\run-impl.js
> C:\dev\myapp\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
> C:\dev\myapp\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
> C:\dev\myapp\node_modules@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
> C:\dev\myapp\node_modules@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
> C:\dev\myapp\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
> C:\dev\myapp\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\init.js
> C:\dev\myapp\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng
> See "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-EHBnHs\angular-errors.log" for further details.
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

I've tried various SO answers like cleaning the cache, updating, re-installing, etc... but I still get this error:

Here the ionic info:
[image]

Any way to get this error fixed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular)

Comment: @MansourAlnasser I tried most of the answers suggested there. Nothing worked.

Comment: check the folder `node_modules` can you find a @angular-devkit/build-angular ?

Comment: also share `ionic info`

Comment: @MansourAlnasser Yes `@angular-devkit/build-angular`  is there but there is no `angular-cli-files` folder under src.

Answer (score 10):

Change devDependencies to
`"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",`
remove folder node_module folder and run `npm i`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after changing system, It can happen while migrating from one version to another.

1. **npm i @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest** .

Try this it may work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem what fix it

1- npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli

2- npm install -g @ionic/cli@6.8.0

3- make a new project in a new folder

4- ionic start

Note: Don't run "npm audit fix"

5- ionic Cordova build android
I hope it works with all

Comment: I did run `npm audit fix`. Do I really need to uninstall the newer version of the ionic/cli and install the 6.8.0 version?

Comment: that is what I made try to make a new project with a new version without run npm audit fix if it doesn't work try 6.8.0