# "ng serve" command shows unhandled exception error

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

Given below is the error message that I recieve

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-MDn3so\angular-errors.log" for further details.​
```

What is the reason for this error ?
My angular CLI version is 12 and the angular core version is 10. I tried updating angular core but it is not being updated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular)

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix for this could be these steps.

1. remove node_modules `rm -rf node_modules` or just delete them
2. run `npm i` or `npm i --only=dev`(only when all modules are already installed just need to save the dev dependencies)
3. run `ng serve` or `npm start`

If the above steps show same error then you should update your dependencies.

1. run `npm update`
2. run `npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular` or `npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular`

Comment: it says "rm" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Thats why I added delete them using normally deleting the folder. rm runs when you are on `Linux` or `Unix` based system. On windows system, it does work with cmdr too if you have it.