# Angular error on Ionic build: Cannot find module '@ionic/angular-toolkit/package.json'

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

When I run "ionic cordova build ios" I get the following error when ng is called:

```
> ng run app:ionic-cordova-build:production --platform=ios
2021-09-29T09:57:54.068Z ng:analytics getGlobalAnalytics
2021-09-29T09:57:54.070Z ng:analytics Client Analytics config found: false
2021-09-29T09:57:54.070Z ng:analytics Analytics disabled. Ignoring all analytics.
2021-09-29T09:57:54.070Z ng:analytics getSharedAnalytics
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@ionic/angular-toolkit/package.json'
Require stack:
- /Users/ralf/n/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
- /Users/ralf/n/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
- /Users/ralf/n/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
- /Users/ralf/n/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/run-impl.js
- /Users/ralf/n/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
- /Users/ralf/n/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
- /Users/ralf/n/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
- /Users/ralf/n/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- /Users/ralf/n/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /Users/ralf/n/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- /Users/ralf/n/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
See "/private/var/folders/y7/p3fxhqk92d30gbk09x6_w5480000gn/T/ng-wCJI7m/angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
```

Here is the output of "ionic info":

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.3 (/Users/ralf/n/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.8.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.2.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.0.5
   @angular/cli                  : 12.0.5
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0, ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 15 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : not installed globally

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.2
   NodeJS     : v14.17.0 (/Users/ralf/n/bin/node)
   npm        : 7.21.1
   OS         : macOS Big Sur
   Xcode      : Xcode 13.0 Build version 13A233
```

I have no idea whats going wrong here. @ionic/angular-toolkit/package.json is available in my project.

Any help on how to fix this would be highly appreciated.

UPDATE: Added package.json

```
{
  "name": "myApp_Phone",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-pwa": "ng build --base-href /",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~12.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^2.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^29.2.0",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.6.22",
    "@firebase/auth": "^0.16.6",
    "@firebase/polyfill": "^0.3.36",
    "@firebase/util": "^1.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/calendar": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/qr-scanner": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "@ionic/storage-angular": "^3.0.6",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "6.0.0",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-calendar": "^5.1.5",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "~6.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^7.8.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^3.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^8.5.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-recentscontrol": "^1.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.5",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^6.0.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "6.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.12.1",
    "cropperjs": "^1.5.12",
    "firebase": "^8.6.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionic4-auto-complete": "^2.9.9",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-image-compress": "^11.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "unorm": "^1.6.0",
    "xcode": "^3.0.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "^3.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.9.1",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/node": "~16.10.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-android": "^9.1.0",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.9.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  },
  "description": "Fortunella myApp Phone",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROIDX_CORE_VERSION": "1.6.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-recentscontrol": {},
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "367618343602117",
        "APP_NAME": "Fortunella App",
        "ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "4.+",
        "FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS": "false",
        "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "5.13.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "com.googleusercontent.apps.58618556950-lotiu9u12l1jo6nmhkr4j1cqovmj346o",
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "15.0.1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-calendar": {
        "CALENDAR_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Add events to your own calendar"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {
        "ANDROID_DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ICON": "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
        "ANDROID_FCM_VERSION": "21.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_BOM_VERSION": "26.0.0",
        "ANDROID_GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION": "4.3.4",
        "ANDROID_GRADLE_TOOLS_VERSION": "4.1.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your `package.json` and try to install the latest version from the plugin using node or yarn `npm i @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest`.

Comment: The installed version 4.0.0 is already the latest version.

Comment: package.json is added to the original post.

Comment: What is strange that "ionic info" shows version 12.2.7 for @angular-devkit/build-angular while in package.json the version is set to ~12.0.1
Maybe that could be the problem?

Comment: if you create a new project can you build it or the same problem show up can you check it ?

Comment: I created a new project with Ionic cli and it builds without any problem. I added ios platform and excuted "ionic cordova build ios". Must be a problem in my specific project.

Comment: Strange, can you try to remove `node_modules` folder and all `platforms` and try to rebuild them `ionic cordova platform rm ios`

Comment: Yes, I did this already several times. Same result.

Comment: Can you share the project with me so I can take a closer look for the problem if that's okay with you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The problem was that I had angular installed globally and the "ionic build" tried to use the global ng version.

After removing the global angular version "ionic build" complaint about a missing @angular/cli. What is strange, because @angular/cli is listed in package.json.

Anyway, after installing it with the proposed npm command the build runs again.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Installed this module to fix the issue.

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find module "@ionic/angular-toolkit" from "/Users/venkat/Documents/www/sgs-birds-web-app/sgsgaushala-app6".
See "/private/var/folders/q6/j4ksfczd66g9xc3wzq7fd9fm0000gp/T/ng-rzJ79t/angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
```

I the issue is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you angular.json has some old configuration.
Check the part: **"For Ionic/Cordova users, you will need to install the new @ionic/cordova-builders package."** so install and verify the new angular configuration and compare with on your project.

https://ionicframework.com/blog/updates-to-ionic-angular-toolkit/