# npm install not installing '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

On a MEAN course project I cannot run it because I am getting the below error:

```
$ npm run start

> mean-course@0.0.0 start
> ng serve

Node packages may not be installed. Try installing with 'npm install'.
Error: Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package.
```

So I go into the package.json file and under "devDependencies" add the line:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server": "15.1.6",
```

Then I try to run npm run start and I get the error below stating that the dependency is still not installed:

```
> mean-course@0.0.0 start
> ng serve

Node packages may not be installed. Try installing with 'npm install'.
Error: Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package.
```

Anybody have the same problem or know a solution? Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: have you run npm install before npm start ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 6 - Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/angular-6-could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular)

Answer (score 1):

Try this command in your terminal:

```
npm i -D @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Comment: Did this and got the following error: $ npm i -D @angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server" of package "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server@15.1.6": name can only contain URL-friendly characters.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\615608\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-16T14_17_48_576Z-debug-0.log

Comment: The package name is `@angular-devkit/build-angular` - without the `:dev-server`

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Comment: I did this and got the following error: $ npm i -save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server" of package "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server@15.1.6": name can only contain URL-friendly characters.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\615608\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-16T14_16_12_813Z-debug-0.log

Comment: did you tried installing --forcefully?
npm i -f