# Getting an error while launching the angular application

Tags: angular, frontend

While launching my angular application via the following command - `ng serve --port 4200 --host 127.0.0.1 --disable-host-check true --ssl true`, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package.
```

I have the @angular-devkit/build-angular package present in my package-lock.json with version 14.0.5, hence I am unable to understand why this error keeps coming up while launching my angular application.

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 6 - Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/angular-6-could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular)

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I have tried this, but to no avail. I have also tried removing npm_modules folder and running a fresh npm install as well. But I keep getting the same error.

Comment: remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and on terminal `npm cache clean --force` and then do `npm i`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this command:

**npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular --legacy-peer-deps**

...to allow old-fashioned dependency resolution, which might avoid some of the dependency conflicts.
All others did not work.