# How to install npm peerDependencies to remove warnings

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

I have seen similar questions on stackoverflow regarding npm peerDependencies warnings - but none address best practices for **actually installing** the dependencies. i.e., are we now supposed to save them along with our `dependencies` and `devDependencies`? If that's the case, what's the purpose of the `peerDependencies` in `package.json`?

After installing some other npm packages, I'm getting a slew of warnings along the lines of:

```
npm WARN slate-prop-types@0.4.32 requires a peer of slate@>=0.32.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

So what I did is set a `peerDependencies` object in `package.json`, and include what it's asking for:

```
...
"peerDependencies": {
  "slate": "0.32.0"
},
...
```

rerun `npm i`, but the warning still persists.

The warning only goes away when I include the peerDependency within devDependencies or dependencies, which I don't really want to do since it muddies what packages my project directly depends on.

What's the right way to go about this?

Comment: Can you try `npm install --save slate@0.32.0`

Comment: @Isaac That will work, but as I mentioned it will save it to `dependencies` which I don't prefer. Is this best practice for dealing with peerDependencies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install npm peer dependencies automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207380/how-to-install-npm-peer-dependencies-automatically)

Comment: See the duplicate: *The automatic install of peer dependencies was explicitly removed with npm 3, as it cause more problems than it tried to solve*

Comment: @Raptor I understand that it has been removed in npm 3 - but what's the best practice for installing them manually? If the peerDependencies object isn't doing anything - what is it's purpose?

Comment: Please read "Peer dependencies" section: https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2016/08/24/understanding-the-npm-dependency-model/

Comment: @Raptor I have read this article - but again it doesn't state HOW to actually go about installing peer dependencies.

Comment: Peer dependencies may not be required. As suggested by Issac, you can install the peer dependencies manually, only when you're told to install the software.

Comment: Having a peerDependencies in your package.json IS about the peer dependencies your package require. Most of the time if you are not developing a package to be installed by others, you don't need this. The warning you are getting is about a package you are depending on requires a peer dependency. In your case `slate-prop-types` requires `slate`; you need to install it manually.

Comment: Oh guys, comon. Just answer the question - HOW TO INSTALL PEER DEPENDENCIES MANUALLY? Is it about running `npm install slate@0.32.0 --no-save`? If so, next run of `npm install` will remove all of the peer dependencies. What if I have a plugin project, and I'm testing it w/o a host app?

Comment: you can reference to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61114706/8175165

Answer (score 0):

When doing npm-install PeerDependencies not installed. Peer Dependencies are listed in the package.json file in the peerDependencies object. They are automatilcally can install using npm, 
 **npm install --save-dev --ignore-scripts install-peers**