# Problems with npm install

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install

I have an expo (react native) project and i want to install from npm react-navigation but when i type 'npm install --only=dev react-navigation' i recive such warnings, idk what to do[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlfY4.png)

and this is my package.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEFnI.png)

i have already tried to uninstall packages from npm and install other version but in vain

Comment: looks like it asks you to install some dependencies as well.. such as `eslint`. simply install them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207380/how-to-install-npm-peer-dependencies-automatically) you can no longer automatically install peer dependencies. Install them manually, then try installing `react-navigation` again.

Comment: the thing is is when i try to install them manually, there are more error i guess it is all because some dependencies for example works with react 16.0.0 but not with 16.3.0 and other packets vice versa

Comment: You'll need to provide further information, such as what these additional errors are, in your original post for it to be possible to provide more detailed guidance.