# Can't bind to 'configuration' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-material-multilevel-menu'

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using [**`ng-material-multilevel-menu`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-material-multilevel-menu) plugin to create multilevel dropdown. I am following [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-material-multilevel-menu) article, but getting below runtime error

> Can't bind to 'configuration'
>   since it isn't a known property of 'ng-material-multilevel-menu'.
>   1. If 'configuration' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
>   2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
>
> Can't bind to 'items' since it isn't a known property of
>   'ng-material-multilevel-menu'.
>   1. If 'items' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
>   2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
>
> 'ng-material-multilevel-menu' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'ng-material-multilevel-menu' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ng-material-multilevel-menu' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.

This is my code in `.html` file

```
 <div>
  <ng-material-multilevel-menu [configuration]='config' [items]='appitems' (selectedItem)="selectedItem($event)">
  </ng-material-multilevel-menu>
 </div>
```

This is my code in `.ts` file

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule } from 'ng-material-multilevel-menu';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule // Import here
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})


export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private employeeService: ProductService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

     var appitems = [
        {
          label: 'Item 1 (with Font awesome icon)',
          faIcon: 'fab fa-500px',
          items: [
            {
              label: 'Item 1.1',
              link: '/item-1-1',
              faIcon: 'fab fa-accusoft'
            },
            {
              label: 'Item 1.2',
              faIcon: 'fab fa-accessible-icon',
              items: [
                {
                  label: 'Item 1.2.1',
                  link: '/item-1-2-1',
                  faIcon: 'fas fa-allergies'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Item 1.2.2',
                  faIcon: 'fas fa-ambulance',
                  items: [
                    {
                      label: 'Item 1.2.2.1',
                      link: 'item-1-2-2-1',
                      faIcon: 'fas fa-anchor'
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
      ];

    });
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: where is component after @Component and module after @NgModule? check angular docs how to basic for modules and components - I think this is the issue.

Comment: @andriishupta  What should I write after `@Component`.

Comment: component class; after module - module class. @Component is a decorator.

Comment: @ Component and @ NgModule are annotations for classes and you don't want to annotate your ProductsComponent with @ NgModule. There must be a separate module class (or app module) where you add your imports. The error "can't bind" in most situations means: No component found with given selector:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Do not use var, just use it like this appitems=[...]
Second: You did not declare the config variable in your controller.
Third: You need to add the NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule  in the AppModule class not in the component you created.

Comment: Could you please write little more like where should I keep config file.

Comment: You need to have it in the same component you want to use it, but if you are going to use in several places it may be a good idea to create a file with the config and import it on each component. It should be declared as the appitems field.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `@NgModule` section from this component file. Add `NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule` in imports section of your `app.module.ts` file.

And declare `appitems` as global variable above the constructor like below:

```
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  appitems: any = [];
  constructor(private employeeService: ProductService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

     this.appitems = [
        {
          label: 'Item 1 (with Font awesome icon)',
          faIcon: 'fab fa-500px',
          items: [
            {
              label: 'Item 1.1',
              link: '/item-1-1',
              faIcon: 'fab fa-accusoft'
            },
            {
              label: 'Item 1.2',
              faIcon: 'fab fa-accessible-icon',
              items: [
                {
                  label: 'Item 1.2.1',
                  link: '/item-1-2-1',
                  faIcon: 'fas fa-allergies'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Item 1.2.2',
                  faIcon: 'fas fa-ambulance',
                  items: [
                    {
                      label: 'Item 1.2.2.1',
                      link: 'item-1-2-2-1',
                      faIcon: 'fas fa-anchor'
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
      ];

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define config in your ProductsComponent :

```
config = {
    paddingAtStart: true,
    interfaceWithRoute: true,
    classname: 'my-custom-class',
    listBackgroundColor: `rgb(208, 241, 239)`,
    fontColor: `rgb(8, 54, 71)`,
    backgroundColor: `rgb(208, 241, 239)`,
    selectedListFontColor: `red`,
    highlightOnSelect: true,
    collapseOnSelect: true,
    rtlLayout: false
};
```