# Install a peer of something

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I was about to install pug --> `npm install --save pug` --> when I got a lot of "npm warn" telling me that a lot of different npm modules requires a lot of peers from other modules or something.

Now, I have no idea on what a peer of something is, moreover, I have no clue whatsoever on how to install the peers. Do I just type `npm install --save NAME_OF_REQUIRED_PEER`?

[image]
[image]

It seems like there is no end to the warnings but perhaps that is just because I am not installing the peers correctly.

Comment: This question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207380/how-to-install-npm-peer-dependencies-automatically

Comment: I am not trying to install them "automatically" that is also deprecated. I want to install them as they are "meant" to be installed, but I just don't know how to do so. This is my question ^^