# failed to load csv file using csv-loader

Tags: webpack, papaparse, webpack-loader

I am learning webpack-loader, and using csv-loader to load a csv file.
[image]
[image]
I have already install the csv-loader and add the rule. However, webpack log an

> error:  Cannot find module 'papaparse'.
>   [image]

How do this error happened?

Comment: just install the papaparse will solve the problem...

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, it looks like `papaparse` is declared as a dependency within `csv-loader` which [does not install by default after npm 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207380/how-to-install-npm-peer-dependencies-automatically). You can just install it yourself using the following:

```
npm install --save-dev papaparse
```