# Does NPM have a flag for peer dependency install?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

Looking through the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) I see `-S`, `-O`, `-D` etc. options for installing dependencies, but I don't see a flag for installing to the peer dependency block.

Does NPM have a flag for installing to peer dependencies?

Comment: Duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207380/how-to-install-npm-peer-dependencies-automatically

Comment: No that's different.  That's after the peer dependencies are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5,

Peer dependencies won't be automatically installed and you must install them manually.

If you want to save peer dependencies for your project, install with the --peer flag.

Comment: I tried `--peer` but the dependency is still added to the `dependencies` block.

Comment: `npm i --peer cuid`

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no CLI flag to install as a peer dependency.

You will need to manually edit `package.json` to add a property `peerDependencies`.

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "cuid": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies