# ESLint plugins need Vue and Vuetify but I want to have them only as peer-dependencies

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, eslint, package.json

I'm developing a module that uses Vue and Vuetify. They are peer dependencies because if they're not, I will have two instances of Vue, which is bad (one in the main app, and one in the module).

My problem is I want to use ESLint with Vue and Vuetify plugins, but ESLint seems to need Vue and Vuetify as real dependencies. If not, I've got the following error message when linting:

```
Error: Failed to load plugin 'vuetify' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module 'vuetify/es5/components/VGrid/VContainer'
```

Answer (score 1):

`eslint-plugin-vuetify` needs the `vuetify` package for its [`grid-unknown-attributes` rule](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/eslint-plugin-vuetify/blob/01de7ff/lib/rules/grid-unknown-attributes.js#L9-L11).

The solution is to **install the peer dependencies**. With NPM 7+, the [peer dependencies are automatically installed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35207983/6277151). For earlier NPM versions or Yarn users, the peer dependencies must be manually installed, which can be done with this command (using the [`npm-install-peers` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-peers)):

```
npx npm-install-peers
```