# npm WARN @ octokit / plugin-request-log @ 1.0.3 requires a peer of @ octokit / core @> = 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies

Tags: npm

I have the following problem, install xampp and composer, when installing NPM it gives me the following warning:

> npm WARN @ octokit / plugin-request-log @ 1.0.3 requires a peer of @ octokit / core @> = 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

And I don't know how.

Comment: `npm install @octokit/core`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install npm peer dependencies automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207380/how-to-install-npm-peer-dependencies-automatically)