# Why does NPM 7.17 not install my peer dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have a `main` project which depends on a package `package1` in the local file store. `package1` peer depends on express:

```
{
  "name": "package1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

In the folder of the main project I do

```
npm install ../packages/package1
```

With npm@6.x it installs package1 as a link in node_modules of the main project, as expected. It also gives me a warning, that a peer dependency is missing - as expected.

Now I use npm@7.17 for the same task. Either with `--legacy-peer-deps` option or without. It installs package1 as a link in node_modules of the main project. But it does NOT install the peer dependency in the main package NOR does it give my a warning, that a peer dependency is missing.

I exepected either a warning (at least with `-legacy-peer_deps` switched on) or `express` installed in the main project. BTW, it also does not get installed in the node_modules of package1.

Any idea anybody? I'd appreciate it much.

Comment: There is a discussion in npm repository: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2339.

Answer (score 0):

The same is happening to me, and based on this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/57915074/473967 looks like `peerDependencies` are for the host package but won't install on the "plugin" package, so we need to add it twice, on the dependencies (or devDependencies) AND on the peerDependencies to let the host know.