# Node install npm modules

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I'd like to install npm modules based on package.json

I'd like to know if there is anyway to automate installing modules.

For instance dependencies of package.json is as follows.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.1.0",
    "jade": "*",
    "stylus": "*",
    "mongodb": ">= 0.9.6-7"
  }
```

do I have to install modules one by one like this?

```
npm install express@3.1.0
npm install mongodb@0.9.6
```

and etc.

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation about `npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

> By default, npm install will install all modules listed as dependencies in package.json.

So you can just type `npm install`.

Comment: I installed modules by npm install command. But it looks like only express is installed

Comment: @David What do you mean exactly by "it looks like"? `npm install` should install *all* packages from packages.json. Did you get an error message during installing?

Answer (score 0):

when you are installing first time use --save, that module installation info will be added to package json

after that at new location you just need to run npm install

npm install express@3.1.0 --save

npm install mongodb@0.9.6 --save

npm install

also refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by typing:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install npm

use nvm to switch versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a specific version of module you should use

```
npm install module_name@version --save
```

`--save` add's the module and the version of the module to your `package.json` file's `dependencies`. If you want to install just any version of a module you can use

```
npm install module_name --save
```

if you don't use `--save` at the and node would still install the last version of the module you want but it wouldn't add it to your `package.json` file . In this case you have some specific versions of some modules in your `package.json` file if you want to install them, you can simply use the

```
npm install
```

command. `npm install` installs all modules in your `package.json` file.

Also if you are new in nodeJs you can check [this](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/) out. I hope this helps. Have a good day good sir.

Answer (score -1):

You could install modules written in package.json as follows.

`npm install`