# What does the `--save` do when you add it to `npm install`?

Tags: node.js, npm

What does the `--save` do when you add it to `npm install`? I tried looking for documentation on this but couldn't find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the --save option for npm install?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install)

Comment: The documentation for this is everywhere

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a `package.json` file (you should have, if not - just run `npm init`) the module you just installed is added to this file to the dependencies section.

It's very usefull in many cases, not just for documentation. For example: you want to move your project - you don't need to install manually all of your modules or copy the node_modules folder. just run `npm install` and npm will install all the dependencies.

P.S. I have no idea in which documentation you looked... Just google the same words of your question...