# Amazon lambda nodejs elasticache store data in redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, models, aws-lambda, amazon-elasticache

I have a lambda function(runtime: Nodejs 4.3) and I need to store data in elasticache. The engine is redis. This is my function:

```
const redis = require("redis");
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    callback(null, {});
};
```

Lambda returns `"errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'redis'",` error.
Should I add nom redis package in zip?

Comment: Yes, you need to include everything in your node_modules directory in the zip.

Comment: Who knows, why imagesmagick, aws-sdk exists.. packages exist by default, but redis does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

All npm modules needs to be installed in node_modules folder. You can use npm install --save package name command to install node_module and save its name in package.json. Refer this link for --save option [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install).

Zip the index.js and node_moule for upload. index.js file is your handler function, if your handler name is different, use that name for js file and zip file.

**Note:-** It is best to use node-lambda module for developing your code on local ec2 machine. Execute it with the node-lambda run and use node-lambda deploy for deploying the code over lambda. Zipping and all other things will be taken care by node-lambda.