# No dependencies in package.json file, after npm init

Tags: json, node.js

I am trying to start a new project that require node.js. After I create a folder, I am trying to make `node_modules` to show up in my project folder. Therefore, I use

```
npm init
```

and then, I use

```
npm install
```

after the installing it, I realized that my `node_modules` folder is empty, so I checked out the `package.json`. I realized that there is no dependencies

is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: npm install package_you_need --save-dev. see [doco](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: you have not installed any packages yet, try npm install express --save and you will see express inside your node_modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do npm init you might have entered the values like the below in CLI:

```
name: (testApp) 
Sorry, name can no longer contain capital letters.
name: (testApp) testApp
Sorry, name can no longer contain capital letters.
name: (testApp) test-app
version: (1.0.0) 
description: This is a test app
entry point: (index.js) app.js
test command: npm test
git repository: 
keywords: 
author: Sagar Gopale
license: (ISC) 
About to write to /home/sagargopale/Projects/testApp/package.json:
```

Then there is package.json created as follows with the above configuration:

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a test app",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm test"
  },
  "author": "Sagar Gopale",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

When you install any dependency it will add the dependencies block in package.json. For example if I do

```
npm install express --save
```

then the package.json will look like below:

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a test app",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm test"
  },
  "author": "Sagar Gopale",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Everyone is talking about using --save when it is supposed to be the [default ][1]

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install

I did the same as the OP, and then installed a couple modules, but the dependencies node in the package.json is still EMPTY (latest of everything). 

But magically, everything still works !

Even a Dockerfile referencing this seems to just work within the container.

Seems like this node is redundant now and is smart enough to know whats needed from the code and as is their norm they failed to document it?