# Why is my "npm install" downloading a lot of excess libraries that I did not specify?

Tags: javascript, json, npm, mean

This is my package.json dependencies array:

```
{
  "cookie-parser": "~1.0.1",
  "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
  "express": "~3.5.0",
  "socket.io":"1.0",
  "mongodb":"2.2.21",
  "request":"2.79.0", 
  "q":"1.4.1", 
  "bcryptjs":"2.4.0", 
  "jsonwebtoken":"7.2.1",
  "lodash":"4.17.4",
  "express-jwt": "5.1.0"
}
```

and then when i perform an NPM install this is the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVUVz.jpg

Why am I getting all of this? On one PC I'm only getting the dependencies I requested but on my laptop I get all of this. I am very confused. I have the output as well but it looks ugly when pasted here.

Comment: Many packages require other packages in order to work so those get downloaded as a part of the package you specified in your `package.json` file.

Comment: You sure the extra folders aren't dependencies of your dependencies?

Comment: look at the `package.json` for the dependencies you have listed in your `package.json`

Answer (score 3):

The packages you're installing have dependencies - this means that when you install them, you're also installing their dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and created a mock `package.json` with your dependencies and did an `npm install`.

Indeed, the packages actually displayed were the ones listed, but an `npm ls` will show all of the dependencies each of *those* dependencies installed, as noted by **Pineda** in a comment on your question.

You can use `npm ls` to view the dependency structure. Full documentation can be found here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls

Comment: I feel my answer is more complete than the one submitted above, which is effectively a one-liner. - Is there any feedback to guide me in future answers?

Answer (score 1):

To dispel any weirdness regarding packages (which happens to me too), it's best to delete `node_modules` folder and `npm i` again. After that, combination of dependencies in your `package.json` (both dev-dependencies and normal-ones), should match the output of the command: `npm ls --depth="0"`.

Now, on both your PC and your laptop the `npm ls --depth="0"` **will** match the combined list of all dependencies in `package.json`. Both cannot mismatch, otherwise that would mean npm became self-conscious and went rogue .

Now, the readers of SO down-voted your question assuming you don't understand that dependencies can have dependencies and that's where the folders are coming from.

I hope that's not the case and that you will not get discouraged by any negativity happening in SO.

There is **another possible scenario** which might explain your case.

If you forgot to add `--save` when installing dependencies, dependencies were just saved into `node_modules` folder, **but not added** to your `package.json`. Thus, you might have inadvertently installed more things that you use.

When you delete the `node_modules` folder and install again, all dependencies are wiped and **only what was in package.json** is installed. That's why I suggest to delete `node_modules` folder first. As a note, npm-publishing automation libraries like my preferred [np](https://www.npmjs.com/package/np) tend to wipe and reinstall dependencies before publishing the npm packages because of this exact reason. There can be "rubbish" in `node_modules` and wipe/reinstall helps.

I suggest to refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19578808/3943954) brilliant answer on `--save`.

With regards of previous answers, Jonathan mentioned `npm ls` but I find it unwieldy on anything else than trivial libraries — too much scrolling. It's best to use `npm ls --depth="0"` to check just the topmost level of your dependencies.